# Average of imported list (python)

Tags: python, list, numpy, sum, average

I'm trying to get the average of a list that has the following format:
`[["195", "106", "100", "95"]]`.

Now `sum(list1)` does not work (used for `sum(list1)/len(list1)`(while `len(list1)` works fine):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

If the list were like this `[195,106,100,95]` it would work. The same goes wrong if I use `numpy.mean(list1)`. Is there something I can add so this will work? Or maybe a way for me to quickly convert the list format?

Comment: I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` instead, because your list contains strings, not integers.

Comment: Are you **certain** that your `list1` doesn't contain another list object?

Comment: Duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list

Comment: Your sample list works just fine when converting to integers first: `sum(map(int, list1))`.

Comment: Yes indeed I forgot, My list is actually a matrix: [["195", "106", "100", "95"]]

Comment: @SecondLemon try to post the exact input at very first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a matrix you need to sum the elements of the *nested* lists. You also need to convert those to integers:

```
total = sum(int(i) for sublist in outerlist for i in sublist)
length = sum(len(sublist) for sublist in outerlist)
average = total / length
```

This assumes you wanted the average of all numbers across all nested lists together, so the length needs to reflect the nested list lengths, not the outer list.

Demo using Python 3:

```
>>> outerlist = [["195", "106", "100", "95"]]
>>> total = sum(int(i) for sublist in outerlist for i in sublist)
>>> length = sum(len(sublist) for sublist in outerlist)
>>> total / length
124.0
```

Comment: Sorry I've been a bit too vague. I will give you the exact script I've got now.

 `>>> list0 = [["180", "108", "190", "120"],["190", "102", "100", "120"],["195", "104", "190", "120"],["205", "109", "100", "120"]]


>>> list1 = list(map(lambda x:x[0],list0))`

Now I would like the sum of list1

Comment: Strange, now it suddenly works. Anyway `sum(map(int, list1))` works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

this error because the elements are strings
if you want to get the average use this code

```
from __future__ import division #for the exact division
x = ["195", "106", "100", "95"]
x_int = [int(y) for y in x]
print sum(x_int) / len(x_int)
```

Comment: No, the error message shows the OP has a **list** object in the sequence.