# Find GPA from grades array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to take number of subjects, then take grade letter of each
by calling findGradePoint and then return GPA

```
def findGradePoint(g):
gradeLetter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
gradePoint = [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]

for i, v in enumerate(gradeLetter):
    if v==g:
        gp = gradePoint[i]

return gp




def findGPA(n, ls):
totGp = 0.0
g = len(str,[ls])
for i in g:
    gp = findGradePoint(i)
    totGp = totGp + gp
return round(totGp / len[g],2)
```

I don't know how to split each value in the array to check grade point for each value and sum all the value then devide them by number count of value in array. Guide me please.

test file

```
import unittest
import a07

a = a07

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testA(self):
        self.assertEqual(a.findGPA(4, ['B','B','B','C']), 2.75)
    def testB(self):
        self.assertEqual(a.findGPA(4, ['B','B','B','A']), 3.25)
    def testC(self):
        self.assertEqual(a.findGPA(7, ['C','C','C','C','B','B','F']), 2)
    def testD(self):
        self.assertEqual(a.findGPA(4, ['C','D','F','B']), 1.5)


def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Tell us what the input looks like, and what you want the output to look like. Your findGPA function takes `n`, which is never used, and `ls`. 

What is `ls`?

Comment: `sum(l) / len(l)` would be simpler I guess

Comment: let say input is (4, ['B','B','B','C']) the answer should be 2.75

Comment: what about `sum(dict(zip("FDCBA",range(5)))[i] for i in l)/float(len(l))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the average of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To focus strictly on your code since you seem to already have a working `findGradePoint` method, you have quite a few problems. I ran your code with the fixed `findGPA` method, and got it working.

To explain what you are doing wrong:

You defined `n` in your method definition, but it is not used. I don't think you need it. So you can probably remove it.

```
def findGPA(n, ls):
```

The following is incorrect, `len` only takes one argument. Here is the documentation on [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len). So this should be removed.

```
g = len(str,[ls])
```

Your loop below, since you don't need that `g = len(str,[ls])` should be changed form this:

```
for i in g:
```

To simply this:

```
for i in ls
```

Your sum step, can be easily shortened to just this:

```
totGp += gp
```

You again are not using the len() method correctly here:

```
return round(totGp / len[g],2)
```

`len` is a method, and you are treating it like a list. It is to be used as:

```
return round(totGp / len(ls), 2)
```

When you make all those corrections, your working method is here:

```
def findGPA(ls):
    totGp = 0.0
    for i in ls:
        gp = findGradePoint(i)
        totGp += gp
    return round(totGp / len(ls), 2)
```

Demo:

```
r = findGPA(['A', 'C', 'D'])
print(r)
# output 2.33
```

Comment: Sorry for hard understanding. I alredy got an output for findGradePoint for functon I used above. I'm currently have a bit of problem with findGPA

Comment: @CatFat look at my updated answer. Let me know what you think.