# average of i-th position elements of a list in a dictionary python

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a following list of dictionaries:

```
clusters=[{'A': [1.0, 1.0]}, {'C': [4.0, 4.0], 'D': [4.0, 5.0], 'B': [2.0, 1.0]}]
```

I have written a snippet of code to access one dictionary at a time from the list:

```
for index, value in enumerate(clusters):
        for key in value:
```

such that i get the following dictionaries;

```
{'A': [1.0, 1.0]}
{'C': [4.0, 4.0], 'D': [4.0, 5.0], 'B': [2.0, 1.0]}
```

What i am trying to do is find the average of `ith` element of the list value in the dictionary.
For example: In the second dictionary;

```
x-position-average = (4.0+4.0+2.0)/3
```

and then assign that value to a dictionary as:

```
new_centroid = {"X": x-position-average,"Y": y-position-average,...}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the average of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Comment: @Trey50Daniel i reckon both questions only sound same.

Comment: Yeah I think so. That's what threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "sum" method.
Given a dictionary "D":

```
def average(D, i):
    # key iterates over all keys in the dictionary. 
    # D[key][i] is the ith element of the list whose key is "key"
    return sum(D[key][i] for key in D)/len(D)
```

This returns the average of the ith element of every list in D.

Comment: could you please add more description?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dictionary of points in dimension `n` the following function returns their centroid as a tuple:

```
def centroid(d,n):
    return tuple(statistics.mean(d[k][i] for k in d) for i in range(n))
```

For example, if

```
cluster = {'C': [4.0, 4.0], 'D': [4.0, 5.0], 'B': [2.0, 1.0]}
```

Then

```
>>> centroid(cluster,2)
(3.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335)
```

This uses the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module, which is relatively new in Python 3.