# Read each line in a text file, store the values in a list, and compute scores

Tags: python, arrays, list

Read each line in a text file, store the values in a list, and compute scores

Comment: Welcome to SO. Homework like questions tend to be poorly received here unless the asker makes some attempt at solution (i.e. some code)  and focuses the question on where they are unclear. Also, please edit  to format your sample data, it is unclear if this sample data has a header or not.

Comment: As paisanco stated, this community will be ecstatic to help you once you make an honest effort to solve the problem and to actually study some Python. It is hard to believe that you got this assignment without being given any direction or material to study.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach this problem is to list all the functions you need to do the task. A typical example is:

1. Read file.
2. Read list.
3. Take list and get each string delimited by space.
4. Store string into an array.
   ...

Then go to the Python website and lookup how to do each function.

Example: To do input and output function in python:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Also, you can look up function by asking google. Google will then point you to answers to your questions:

Q: How to find mean of a list?
A: [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

If you do this enough times, eventually you will be able to write a problem that solves the problem listed.

Good Luck!