# How to calculate mean in python data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ipython

I need to calculate [mean] for only some particular variable in a data set.
I have a data frame in python contain variables like 
ID,Name,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,June.
With this variable i have to create a new variable like "Avgmnth". by calculating the mean only for Feb,Mar,Apr

How to calculate this in python.Help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the search function next time.
If I understood your question correct you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039992/6459948)?

As answered by @Herms

> If your reduce is already returning your sum, then all you have left
>   to do is divide.
>
> ```
> l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
> print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)
> ```
>
> though `sum(l)/len(l)` would be simpler, as you wouldn't need a
>   lambda.
>
> If you want a more exact float result instead of an int then just use
>   `float(len(l))` instead of `len(l)`.

Comment: It may be better to flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: how can you do that? i'm quite new here

Comment: Thank you @UpZone. Looks good.