# Using function len() in python3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

When I need to count the number of positive numbers in a given range (ex, range-->>(1,100)),
I use function `len()`, but it doesn't work and gives:

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Can someone explain this error, or suggest the correct function to use with this problem.

Comment: `len` is the right function to use to get the length of a sequence, but it sounds like you're not calling it on a sequence but rather a single integer. Please show the code you're running and the full exception traceback and we'll be able to help you understand what's happening.

Comment: `len(1)` produces the given `TypeError` exception; `len(range(1,100))` returns 99, as expected.  As [Blckknght](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght) says, we need to see your problem code.

Comment: @MahaTaha: What are you trying to do there? You're generating `int`s, which don't have a concept of length, why would you think `len` would work?

Comment: @MahaTaha: Please edit the code into the question so you can format it properly.

Comment: @MahaTaha: Again, what on Earth are you expecting? In the new code, you're trying to take the length of what you just made a `float`. What is the length of a `float` to you? Are you trying to accumulate several `float`s in a `list`? If you can't figure that out, stop trying to write this code and use a proper Python tutorial instead of flailing wildly and hoping. Or take a class that provides hands-on assistance, this sort of ultra-basic stuff isn't practical to teach on StackOverflow question at a time.

Comment: my input six nos EX( 7 , -5 , 6 , -3.4 , 4.6 , 12 )... and the output tell me that there are (4 positive no)....Understand me ??!!!.

Comment: It's really a bad idea to code something before you've read at least Python Tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

[len(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) takes as an argument a

> sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dicttionary, set, or frozen set).

That is, `len(s)` can only be called - and only makes sense - on one of those data structures.

Passing an `int` will fail with the posted error - it simply doesn't make sense, `int`s don't have length.

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

As such, something like `len(range(1,100))`, or `len([1,2,3])` works, but `len(1)` doesn't.

In your example, in the comments:

```
for s in range(10):  
  if s>0: 
    print(len(s))
```

`s` is an int, a different one in the `range(10)` in every loop, which explains why `len(s)` fails.

P.S. Posting a direct snippet from your code may help the answerers get a better understanding of the problem you are having.

**Update:** From your comments and code it is evident that you are trying to store a `list` of inputs.

```
input_list = []
for s in range(0,6): 
  d=float(input())
  if d>0:
    input_list.append(d)
    print("")
print (len(input_list))
```

When you do the assignment `d=float(input())`, `d` will be a different value every loop, a `float`, hence `len(d)` fails. What you want is to store all your inputs in a list `input_list` and then print the `len` of that. You can store values in a list by `append()`ing them - `input_list.append(d)`

Comment: thanks for your effort man ... it's work

Comment: @MahaTaha My pleasure! Always aim to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your questions, so that SO users can better help you. I'd recommend that you read a good [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/) to get a good grasp of these things, and read more about python's [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html). As well, remember to upvote any good questions, and select an answer (if there is one that answers your question), after you have given everyone enough time to answer (a day or so).

Comment: i got  it ... thanks so much for UR advice .... but i've Q: how i can get the ave of this positive nos

Comment: [sum(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)/[len(s)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#len)  `sum(input_list)/len(input_list)` for your code. Trying googling such question, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list) shows as the top result, and it has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely calling `len` on an individual integer rather than the output of the `range`. Instead, use it as such:

```
>>> len(range(1, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve this problem is to filter the range and then count the results:

```
num_positives = len([i for i in range(1, 10) if i > 0])
print(num_positives)
```