# Finding the average pH through files

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, average

My code is supposed to calculate and print the average pH for every fluid given the file variable name.
This is what I have so far, trying to separate the txt file into parts using `split()`.
I don't really know how to separate the function line by line to calculate each pH and print it separately.

Right now it prints nothing, since it most likely doesn't see a number in the first slot

Function

```
def average_ph(file_variable):

    result = 0
    line = file_variable.readline()
    found = False
    while line != "" and not found:
        list = line.strip().split(",")
        if list.isnum:
            result += list
    if line != "":
        avg = result / 3
    if not found:
        result = None
        print(avg)
    return avg
```

Main

```
file_name = str(input("Enter a file name: "))
file_variable = open(file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

File - named: pH.txt

```
Lemon juice,2.4,2.0,2.2
Baking soda (1 Tbsp) in Water (1 cup),8.4,8.3,8.7
Orange juice,3.5,4.0,3.4
Battery acid,1.0,0.7,0.5
Apples,3.0,3.2,3.5
```

Comment: As a start, your indentation is not correct. The code should be indented compared to your function signature.

Comment: yeah you're right

Comment: 1) You can loop over a file with `for line in file:` 2) Do not name your variable as `list`

Comment: ok, so your list variable contains something like this :
['Lemon Juice', '2.4', '2.0', '2.2']

Now you need to do a for loop on it to get those items.

lines = line.strip().split(",") 
    for item in lines
      if item.isnumeric():
         result += item

In your while loop, you also need to change the found variable to true sometime, otherwise it will keep on going forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boy, where to start?

```
list = line.strip().split(",")
if list.isnum:
```

First, `list` is the name of a built-in type in Python, and while you *can* overshadow that by using it as a variable name, for the sake of not confusing yourself and everybody else, you really shouldn't:

```
lst = line.strip().split(",")
if lst.isnum:
```

OK, that's better. `lst` is an instance of the class that can now still be referred to as `list`.   Now, your `if lst.isnum:` appears to be an attempt to test the output of a method of that instance.  But in Python you can't call methods without typing the parentheses. Without parentheses, currently, your `if` statement is asking whether the *pointer to the method itself* is non-zero which, for methods that exist, is always going to be true...

```
lst = line.strip().split(",")
if lst.isnum():
```

OK, that's better.  Except note that I said, "...for methods that exist". `isnum` is not a method of the `list` class so the code will just raise an exception here. You presumably mean the string method `.isnumeric`:

```
lst = line.strip().split(",")
if lst.isnumeric():
```

But of course this is still wrong. You want to test whether items ***in*** the list are numeric. Therefore, you need to call some function or method of each item, *not* of the list itself.  Although strings have an `isnumeric` method, the `list` class (to which our `lst` variable belongs) does not.  One elegant way around this is to use a "list comprehension":

```
lst = line.strip().split(",")
lst = [item for item in lst if item.isnumeric()]
```

But of course that doesn't actually convert the items from strings to numbers. Did you really think you could just add up a bunch of *strings* and divide by 3?

```
lst = line.strip().split(",")
lst = [float(item) for item in lst if item.isnumeric()]
```

OK, now we have a list of actual floating-point numbers that can be manipulated numerically.  But we've thrown away the information about which substance we're measuring.

```
lst = line.strip().split(",")
substance = lst.pop(0)   # remove and store the first item in the list
lst = [float(item) for item in lst if item.isnumeric()]
```

I would then suggest that you somehow associate each pH value-list/average with its respective substance—otherwise that associative info is going to get lost/corrupted. There are neat ways of doing that with a `dict`, although currently you have a variable called `found` that is unused—suggesting that you may be intending to do something like:

```
if substance == the_particular_substance_we_are_currently_interested_in:
    found = True
    avg = ...
```

(Note: if you do this, do it *inside* the loop—you want to check *each* line to see if it's the target, after all.)

Now, as for your `result += lst`... Well, you initialized `result` to `0` so it's an integer, and `lst` as we know is a `list`. You can't add a `list` to an integer—it doesn't make sense. What you presumably want to do is `sum` the values in the list (and you won't even need `result`):

```
    avg = sum(lst) / len(lst)
```

Note that I'm dividing by whatever the length of `lst` is, rather than hard-coding the number 3 in there. Hardcoding assumptions like that is a really effective way to set hard-to-find traps for your future self, so let's avoid it.

Good luck.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. And you're one of them. Thanks for the insanely detailed explanation you gave me with all those tips for my future coding also.

Comment: Who says I don't wear a cape?

Answer (score 2):

Python3 has a [built-in mean function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071982/2308683)

You just need to figure out how to properly read over a file and split the data.

```
from statistics import mean

with open("pH.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    data = line.split(",")
    ph_values = map(float, data[1:])
    print("{}, avg = {:.02f}".format(data[0], mean(ph_values))
```

As output, should see

```
Lemon juice, avg = 2.20
Baking soda (1 Tbsp) in Water (1 cup), avg = 8.47
Orange juice, avg = 3.63
Battery acid, avg = 0.73
Apples, avg = 3.23
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
def average(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)


def read_average(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        dict
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line.split(',')
            name = data[0]
            avg = average([float(i) for i in data[1:]])
            print("{name}: {avg}".format(name=name, avg=avg))

read_average('pH.txt')
```

Output:

```
Lemon juice: 2.2
Baking soda (1 Tbsp) in Water (1 cup): 8.466666666666667
Orange juice: 3.6333333333333333
Battery acid: 0.7333333333333334
Apples: 3.233333333333333
```