# Average -Python

Tags: python, list, file, average

I am trying to find the average of numbers in ranges (i.e. find the average of all numbers in range 1-1000). I wrote the following code to do this, but the due to the `if-statement`, when run, the code produces multiple numbers. I then tried a `while-loop` instead, but when I entered a `break` statement, it produced the same `list` the `if-statement` produced. Is there any way to use an `if-statement` and get 1 single number that is the average? Thank you!

```
mylist =[]
def ave_data(x, y):
    for line in filename:    
        for number in line.split():
            if int(number) > x and int(number) < y:
                mylist.append(int(number)) 
                print(sum(mylist)/len(mylist))
```

Comment: just de-indent the print 3 lvls and you should be fine

Comment: your `print` statement is in the loop so will be done every time through. Just move it outside of the for-loop so it's done once after `mylist` is populated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SteveFrancisco Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It is *not* due to the if statement. You simply put the `print(..)` in the `if` in the `for` loop. By moving it outside the outer `for`, it will print the average **for the entire file**:

```
def ave_data(x, y):
    mylist = []  # move inside
    for line in filename:    
        for number in line.split():
            if int(number) > x and int(number) < y:
                mylist.append(int(number)) 
    print(sum(mylist)/len(mylist))  # for the entire file.
```

You also move the `mylist` variable better **inside** the function. Otherwise it is a global variable, and other functions can alter it. Furthermore a second run would take the average of the two files.

That being said, you make things too complicated. You can simply use:

```
def ave_data(x, y):
    mylist = [int(number) for line in filename for number in line.split()
                          if x < int(number) < y]
    print(sum(mylist)/len(mylist))  # for the entire file.
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `list-comprenehsion` instead of `for-loop`, as the following:

```
mylist = [int(num) for line in filename for num in line.split() if y > int(num) > x]
print sum(mylist) / len(mylist)
```

You can also add a condition to check if the `list` is empty:

```
print sum(mylist) / len(mylist) if mylist else 'No numbers in that range'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing multiple numbers because your print statement is within your for loop. Take a look at this pseudocode:

```
create an empty list
open the file
for each line in the file
    for each number in the line
        if the number is within the range
            add the number to the list
            compute the average of the list of numbers
```

You see, you are computing the average every time you find a number within the required range. Instead, what you want to do is to gather all the numbers first (within the for loop), and then (outside the for loop) compute the average:

```
create an empty list
open the file
for each line in the file
    for each number in the line
        if the number is within the range
            add the number to the list
compute the average of the list of numbers
```

This is achieved with this code:

```
def ave_data(x, y):
    nums = []
    for line in filename:    
        for number in line.split():
            if int(number) > x and int(number) < y:
                nums.append(int(number)) 
    print(sum(mylist)/len(mylist))
```

Here's a slightly better way to do the same thing:

```
def ave_data(x,y):
    total = 0
    nums = 0
    with open('path/to/file') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            for num in line.split():
                num = int(num)
                if not (x < num < y): continue
                total += num
                nums += 1

    if not nums:
        print("There were no numbers within the required range")
        return

    print("The average is", total/nums)
```