# Couting Numbers in ranges -Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program that relays the number of integers in every 10,000,000 integers. There are over 1 billion integers in the file. The output needs to go to a different file. Is there a function I can use that will loop through every 10,000,000 integers for me rather than typing count_numbers(0, 10000001) count_numbers(1000000, 20000001) etc. every time? I currently have the following code:

```
f = open("countoutput.txt", "w")
def count_numbers(x, y):
    count = 0
    for line in filename:    
        for number in line.split():
            if int(number) > x and int(number) < y:
                count += 1
    f.write(str(count))
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, we already answered that question...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: OP has only this one question on their profile (could be a different username), but IIRC the last question was about writing the `count_numbers` function, not automating its usage

Comment: You could just pass in 1 number like 10000001 and then do `if int(number) > (x-10000001) and int(number) < x:`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194037/finding-average-of-numbers-in-list-python) :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: that's exactly the post I was thinking about. [I even answered it yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194198/198633)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I saw a post from yesterday that I based some of this code off of, but it didn't answer my question : (

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a terser way to do this, but here's what I have off the top of my head

```
for low,high in zip(range(0, 10**10, 10**7), range(10**7 +1, 10**10, 10**7)):
    count_numbers(low, high)
```

Comment: Would that loop through all of the file, or would I still have to input the range as "low, high"?

Comment: That would loop through the whole file multiple times - once for each low,high pair

Comment: So i would not have to input anything?

Comment: Yes. Run this script and see what happens

Comment: I get a number and then a lot of zeros

Comment: I need the count for each range. The first number was correct, yes, but there are deffinetely not 0 in the other bins.

Comment: do you have any advice on how to fix the problem of the 0's? Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Not without looking at what's in your input

Comment: It is just a lot of random integers 4 bytes long. I unfortunately cannot attach the file.