# How to use a for loop to calculate mean of list of numbers python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, mean

Trying to use a for loop to calculate the mean of a list as I want to practice.

This code is returning 4, 5, and 1 with the test cases. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
def list_mean(p):
total = 0
i = 0
if i < len(p):
    for t in p:
        total = total + p[i]
        i += 1
    return i

mean = i / len(p)
return mean


print list_mean([1,2,3,4])
>>> 2.5

print list_mean([1,3,4,5,2])
>>> 3.0

print list_mean([2])
>>> 2.0
```

Comment: This looks like a good place for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging. Try explaining your logic behind each line to us. There's a couple of lines that really don't make sense and I think it would help you to see that for yourself by thinking about it out loud.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Comment: Also, your function body is wrongly indented and has two `returns`, the latter of which will never be reached.

Comment: @Juan I don't think the goal here should be for OP to figure out the optimal python way to find the average of a list, but rather to learn how to think about programming and debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, of all, you do `return i` which is not intended, I guess.

Second, you do `i / len(p)` instead of `total / len(p)`.

We can go further and get rid of unnecessary parts. As `for` loop will be skipped if `len(p)` equals to zero, we can remove `if i < len(p)` statement. Also, we don't need `i` variable, because Python `for` loop yields each element one by one. So, you can use `total = total + t` instead of `total = total + p[i]`. Probably the last thing here is that `total = total + t` is equivalent to `total += t` in this case.

If you fix all I've mentioned, you should get something similar to this:

```
def list_mean(p):
     total = 0.0
     for t in p:
         total += t
     mean = total / len(p)
     return mean
```

But if you want to calculate mean, you can use this:

```
mean = sum(p) / len(p)
```

Note that for Python 2 you need to explicitly cast the type to `float`:

```
mean = float(sum(p)) / len(p)
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged with Python2.7 `mean = ...`  in the function body should also use floating point division.

Comment: @timgeb you're absolutely right! We can initialize `total` with `0.0` and it should do the trick :)

Comment: You could also mention how neither the variable `i` nor the `if `statement are needed.

Answer (score 0):

is it a school task? is using for loop a mandatory?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
mean_val = sum(a)/len(a)
print mean_val
```

or

```
given = [1,3,4,5,2]
def mean_val(a):
    b = sum(a)/len(a)
    return b
print mean_val(given)
```