# Fastest way to compute average of a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find the fastest way to compute the average of python `list`s. I have millions of `list`s stored in a `dictionary`, so I am looking for the most efficient way in terms for performance.

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list),
If `l` is a list of float numbers, I have

- `numpy.mean(l)`
- `sum(l) / float(len(l))`
- `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)`

Which way would be the fastest?

Comment: `Which way would be fastest?` Why don't you test and let us know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @DeepSpace has suggested, you should try yourself to answer this question.  You might also consider transforming your list into an array before using `numpy.mean`. Use `%timeit` with `ipython` as follows:

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: import numpy
In [3]: from functools import reduce
In [4]: l = random.sample(range(0, 100), 50) # generates a random list of 50 elements
```

#### `numpy.mean` without converting to an np.array

```
In [5]: %timeit numpy.mean(l)
32.5 µs ± 2.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### `numpy.mean` converting to an np.array

```
In [5]: a = numpy.array(a)
In [6]: %timeit numpy.mean(a)
17.6 µs ± 205 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#### `sum(l) / float(len(l))`

```
In [5]: %timeit sum(l) / float(len(l)) # not required casting (float) in Python 3
774 ns ± 20.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

#### `sum(l) / len(l)`

```
In [5]: %timeit sum(l) / len(l)
623 ns ± 27.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

#### `reduce`

```
In [6]: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)
5.92 µs ± 514 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**From slowest to fastest:**

1. `numpy.mean(l)` without converting to array
2. `numpy.mean(a)`after converting list to `np.array`
3. `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)`
4. `sum(l) / float(len(l))`, this applies for Python 2 and 3
5. `sum(l) / len(l)` # For Python 3, you don't need to cast (use `float`)

Comment: To be fair, if you are going to consider using `numpy`, you'll probably have already stored the values in an array, rather than a list. With `a = numpy.array(l)`, `numpy.mean(a)` is twice as fast as `numpy.mean(l)`. I haven't tried longer inputs to see how each scales, either.

Comment: @chepner, I agree with you. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @chepner, I updated my answer, I agree with you that after converting to an array, it becomes as twice as faster than without converting.

Comment: Please try to avoid the use of el (l) as a variable name, especially here on SO.  It looks more like the number 1 in the code font.  Case in point, in this comment font, it looks like a capital i (I).

Comment: I wonder about the relative speed of `statistics.mean()`.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon,
I just did a test with a list of 10 random floats in a list and ran a time test and found numpy to be the fastest.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
import time

l = [0.1, 2.3, 23.345, 0.9012, .002815, 8.2, 13.9, 0.4, 3.02, 10.1]

def test1():
    return np.mean(l)

def test2():
    return sum(l) / float(len(l))

def test3():
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)

def timed():
    start = time.time()
    test1()
    print('{} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
    start = time.time()
    test2()
    print('{} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
    start = time.time()
    test3()
    print('{} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))

timed()
```

As always I'm sure there's a better way to do this but this does the trick.
This was a small list: it would be interesting to see what you find with large lists.