# How to average a value list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can you average the value in a dictionary if it's a list?
What follows is the code I have with the correct answer.
I cannot use slicing techniques

```
dict = {'zy': [1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7]}
# code to average the values
print(dict)
{'zy': 0.85}
```

Comment: You find the mean of a list in a dictionary the exact same way you do for _any list_. The only thing that changes is _how you access that list_. In one case, you do it directly through its variable name. In the other, you do it the _exact same way_ you access _any value inside a dictionary_. Does this answer your question: [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

Just use simple maths:

```
dict['zy'] = sum(dict['zy']) / len(dict['zy'])
```

If you don't want to implement yourself you can use the `statistics.mean` function:

```
from statistics import mean
...
dict['zy'] = mean(dict['zy'])
```

As a side note, don't use built-ins such as `dict` to name your variables. You will shadow the built-in.