# Enumerating through a list of data to find averages, but the lines aren't just numbers

Tags: python, arrays, mean, enumerate

I am new to Python. I am enumerating through a large list of data, as shown below, and would like to find the mean of every line.

```
for index, line in enumerate (data):
    #calculate the mean
```

However, the lines of this particular set of data are as such:

```
[array([[2.3325655e-10, 2.4973504e-10],
       [1.3025138e-10, 1.3025231e-10]], dtype=float32)].
```

I would like to find the mean of both 2x1s separately, then the average of both means, so it outputs a single number.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the usual format of the data? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean? The format of the data is as presented in the question.

Comment: So you have something like `arr = numpy.array([[2.3325655e-10, 2.4973504e-10], [1.3025138e-10, 1.3025231e-10]])`? Then you could do `mean = arr.mean(1).mean()`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not need to enumerate through the list to achieve what you want. You can do it in two steps using list comprehension.

For example,

```
data = [[2.3325655e-10, 2.4973504e-10],
       [1.3025138e-10, 1.3025231e-10]]
# Calculate the average for 2X1s or each row
avgs_along_x = [sum(line)/len(line) for line in data]
# Calculate the average along y
avg_along_y = sum(avgs_along_x)/len(avgs_along_x)
```

There are other ways to calculate the mean of a list in python. You can read about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list).

If you are using numpy this can be done in one line.

```
import numpy as np
np.average(data, 1) # calculate the mean along x-axes denoted as 1
# To get what you want, we can pass tuples of axes.
np.average(data, (1,0))
```