# Python List Statistics not correct

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I try to calculate some stats for a list. But somehow these are not correct:
Code:
import pandas as pd

```
import statistics


list_runs_stats=[4.149432, 3.133142, 3.182976, 2.620959, 3.200038, 2.66668, 2.604444, 2.683382, 3.249564, 3.149947]

list_stats=pd.Series(list_runs_stats).describe()

print (list_stats.mean())
print (list_stats.min())
print (list_stats.max())
print (list_stats.median())
print (list_stats.count())
```

Result:

```
3.6617099664905832
0.467574831924664
10.0
3.10280045
8
```

I think min, max and count is quite obvious that it is not correct.
Excel gives me mean: 3.0640564 and median:3,1415445

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning the output of `describe()` to `list_stats`, you are calculating the min and max of the output of `describe` function

Can you try this this instead?

```
import pandas as pd
list_runs_stats=[4.149432, 3.133142, 3.182976, 2.620959, 3.200038, 2.66668, 2.604444, 2.683382, 3.249564, 3.149947]
df = pd.Series(list_runs_stats)
df.describe()
#Output
count    10.000000
mean      3.064056
std       0.467575
min       2.604444
25%       2.670856
50%       3.141545
75%       3.195773
max       4.149432
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes this works!!
Thank you!
print(df.mean())

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this post can help you out: [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

for example:

```
print(statistics.mean(list_runs_stats)) # would print 3.0640564
```

Comment: You have imported statistics library but you aren't using it. In order to use functions of the library, you need to specify it :)