# Python code that printing an avarage number from the dictionary

Tags: python

I have been working on a code that collecting students name and their score. Then printing their name, their score, their highest score, lowest score, and average score. I have completed to write a code that printing name,score, highest and lowest score.I have not completed average one. I have tried some codes but all of them have not worked so far. could you give me some advice or some code that I can use for the code, please? I visited some website to find some code that I can use for my code.
In the code below I have tried with importing module, but it does not work.
I look forward to hearing some great advice from you guys.

```
from statistics import median
from math import isnan
from itertools import filterfalse

def ScoreList():
    scores = {'name': [], 'score': []}
    while True:
        name = input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished ")
        if name == 'done': break
        scores['name'] += [name]
        score = input('Enter score ')
        scores['score'] += [int(score)]

    return scores

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = ScoreList()
    print(scores)
    maxScore = max(scores['score'])
    print("max score is:", maxScore)
    minScore = min(scores['score'])
    print("min score is:", minScore)
    midScore = mid(scores['score'])
    print("average score is", midScore)
```

I have visited some website to find some codes example that I can use for my code and all of them did not work so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Currently your dictionary only stores a list of names and a list of scores. This is probably not the best way because there will be multiple scores associated with one name. You could instead use the `name` as the key in the dictionary, and a list of scores as the value. Define `scores = {}` in your main function. In the input loop you have to ask, if a name is already present in the dict, if so, append the score, otherwise make a new name entry

```
name = input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished ")
score = int(input('Enter score '))
if name in scores:
    scores[name].append(score)
else:
    scores[name] = [score]
```

Now you can ask for min, max and average score of a student by

```
for student_name in scores:
    student_min = min(scores[student_name])
    student_max = max(scores[student_name])
    student_avg = sum(scores[student_name]) / len(scores[student_name])
    print(student_name, student_min, student_max, student_avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to allow the user to enter one or more scores for one or more students and then calculate the max, min, and average across all students then something like this will work.  `score_dict` uses student name for its keys and one or more scores per student for its values.  `chain` is an easy way to extract those values into a list which makes calculating the results straightforward.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
from statistics import mean

def get_score_dict():
    scores = defaultdict(list)
    while (name := input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished: ")) != "done":
        score = input("Enter score: ")
        scores[name].append(int(score))
    return scores

if __name__ == '__main__':
    score_dict = get_score_dict()
    score_list = list(chain.from_iterable(score_dict.values()))
    print(score_list)
    print(f"Max score: {max(score_list)}")
    print(f"Min score: {min(score_list)}")
    print(f"Avg score: {mean(score_list)}")
```