Python: all items that have a higher than average price in array
As part of a Python course I´m taking I wonder whether anyone can help me with the following question: given a list of food names along with their calories and prices information in the format of [name, calories, price] I want to create a function in Python that returns all items in a new array that have a higher than average price.
Say the input for the above is the following array:
input =[
['ABUELO SUCIO (16oz)',400,26],
['Chick-fil-A Chicken Sandwich',400,6],
['Chicken in Lettuce Cups',900,19],
['Classic French Dip',900,16],
['Grilled Chicken Teriyaki',400,18],
['Medium 8 pc Wing Combo',300,10],
['Pad See You',1000,19],
['Tea Leaf Rice',400,15],
['Udon',300,12],
['Very Cherry Ghirardelli Chocolate Cheesecake',900,10]
]

I am trying to create the method with the def below but not sure what the optimal solution is as am a beginner in Python:
def get_food_selection(food_items):
return sorted(overlap_items)

Any help is appreciated.

First find the average.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list then iterative through the list for instance with a list comprehension and select the ones of interest.

You probably want a function rather than method.

@juanpa.arrivillaga how do you think your comment helps anyone who is learning? If “you should do your own homework” is all you can say maybe best to not say anything at all.

@AllanWind thanks very much for your tips, very insightful!!

Please make sure your code snippets are valid Python.
