# Need help in entering integers into python and more

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer, raw-input

I need help in writing a program that allows the user to enter 10 different integers. If the user tries to enter an integer that has already been entered, the program will alert the user immediately and prompt the user to enter another integer. When 10 different integers have been entered, the average of these 10 integers is displayed.

```
try:
    raw_input("enter number: ")
```

I've entered this 10 times which allows me to enter 10 integers, but I am not sure how to alert the user when they have entered an integer that has already been entered.   Is it something like this?

```
except ValueError:
        print("integer already entered")
```

I also not too sure how to calculate the average                                                       I'm sorry for being vague I have been stuck on this for too long since I am a beginner.

Thank you if u can help

Comment: Help with which part of the program? I don't think writing a program from start to finish is a specific problem.

Comment: Homework should be attempted.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking us to do your homework, which isn't what we're here for. Post some code as well as what you are getting stick on with the solution. We're here to help you learn and that means we'll help you get your work done, not do it for you.

Comment: try:
    num = int(input("enter number: "))                                                           I've entered this 10 times which allows me to enter 10 integers, but I am not sure how to alert the user when they have entered an integer that has already been entered.   Is it something like this?                                     except ValueError:
        print("integer already entered")                                                               I also not too sure how to calculate the average

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, your question is too broad and you have not provided evidence of even attempting the problem.

Regardless, here are a few steps to get you started:

- Look into raw_input() for user input
- You'll need to store the values, so look into data Structures such as 
  lists https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html
- you'll be able to iterate through the list to check if the user input (integer) already exists and respond accordingly
- For the last step, calculating the average, have a look here [Calculating arithmetic mean (average) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-average-in-python)