# Can anybody show me an alternative to [::-1] ? I am trying to print a list in reverse order

Tags: python

```
infile=open("Integers.txt", "r")
ListIntegers=infile.readline().strip("\n").split(";")
def avgFirstThreeDigits(mylist):
    list=[]
    for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
        sumFirstThreeDigits=(int(mylist[i][0])+int(mylist[i][1])+int(mylist[i][2]))
        avg=sumFirstThreeDigits/3
        list.append(avg)
    print(list[::-1])
avgFirstThreeDigits(ListIntegers)
```

Comment: (Sorry for the code)

Comment: Select the code and press "ctrl+k" to format it.

Comment: don't be sorry. edit and format it correctly.

Comment: also, consider using the "search" feature.

Comment: @AtakanAk. What's wrong with `[::-1]`? Is this a homework question?

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes its a homework question we can't use [::-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually reverse a list with the following:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = [a[len(a) - i - 1] for i in range(len(a))]

>>> b
>>> ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: `[a[i] for i in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a list of tuples/vectors averages, you can just do something like this:

```
list_averages = [(sum(v3) / len(v3)) for v3 in list_integers]
```

Or just using another of the multiple ways to calculate the [arithmetic mean average will do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-average-in-python)

About an alternative to `[::-1]`, you can just use [list.reverse](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

But be aware `list.reverse` will modify in place, if you don't want to you could use `list(reversed(list_averages))`. In any case, I don't know why you don't want to use [::-1], that one is a pretty fast choice.