# Average of the value - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM event_db.event_log el, event_db.event_type et
WHERE et.event_type_id = el.event_type_id AND et.name in ('kpi_stats_dumped') AND el.timestamp > str_to_date('2016,12,12','%Y,%m,%d') AND el.timestamp < str_to_date('2017,12,12','%Y,%m,%d')
GROUP BY et.name, date_format(el.timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY et.name, el.timestamp
```

Which will return the result as follows:

```
1440
1441
1546
1234
1235
33
224
```

I need to find the average of the values listed.(1021.85714286)

Can someone be able to help me with the same.

Comment: Like this `select avg(cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt from event_db.event_log el ...) tmp`

Comment: If you want python to do this, there's an existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-average-in-python

Comment: i want mysql query to do this

Comment: @juergend it worked , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer , Now the query is as follows:

```
SELECT avg(cnt) from 
(SELECT count(*) as cnt
FROM  event_db.event_log el ,
      event_db.event_type et
WHERE et.event_type_id = el.event_type_id
      AND et.name IN ( 'kpi_stats_dumped' )
      AND el.timestamp > str_to_date('2016,12,12', '%Y,%m,%d')
      AND el.timestamp < str_to_date('2017,12,12', '%Y,%m,%d')
GROUP BY et.name , date_format(el.timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY et.name, el.timestamp) tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(cnt) as average_count
from 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM event_db.event_log el
    JOIN event_db.event_type et ON et.event_type_id = el.event_type_id
    WHERE et.name in ('kpi_stats_dumped') 
    AND el.timestamp > str_to_date('2016,12,12','%Y,%m,%d') 
    AND el.timestamp < str_to_date('2017,12,12','%Y,%m,%d')
    GROUP BY et.name, date_format(el.timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y')
) tmp
```

Comment: Just a hint - ordering in a subquery (which is needed here only for getting and set of values) is unnecessary and possibly will cause performance issues.