# Python: Trying to run a function multiple times and save values for each run

Tags: python

I am trying to get some data from a numerical simulation I am running.
I have a function that solves my ODE and saves the values I need in a vector, `rv`. I would like to run my function 1000 times and get the mean value of `rv` for each timestep but I can't figure out how to do it.

My first thought was to call the function `1000` times and save the data in an array.

```
for i in range(1000):
    datavector = np.array(0)
    circle(N,dt,x0,y0,phi0,r,T,nu,v,Omega,R)
    datavector = np.append(datavector, rv)
```

But when I do that I got the following error message:
`NameError: name 'rv' is not defined`

I'll attach my code since I'm not very good at explaining. Sorry for it being so messy

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def circle(N,dt,x0,y0,phi0,r,T,nu,v,Omega,R):


kB = 1.38*10**-23 # Boltzmann constant [J/K]plt #math constants
DT = kB*T/(6*math.pi*nu*r)  # Translational diffusion coefficent [m^2/s]
DR = kB*T/(8*math.pi*nu*r**3) # Rotational diffusion coefficent [rad^2/s]
n = 0 #iteration constant


x=x0 #vectors and initial values
y=y0
phi=phi0
phiv= np.array(phi) #vector containing phi-values
xv= np.array(x) #vector containing x-values
yv= np.array(y) #vector containing y-values
rv=np.array(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))
xss=np.array(x) #vector containing start and (soon) end value
yss=np.array(y) # same as above

phiK=math.sqrt(2*DR*dt) #constants used in the iteration
xyK=math.sqrt(2*DT*dt)
Odt=Omega*dt

while n < N: #from 0 -> N-1
    phi = phi + Odt + phiK*np.random.normal(0,1) #eq (9)
    x = x + v*math.cos(phi)*dt + xyK*np.random.normal(0,1) #eq (10)
    y = y + v*math.sin(phi)*dt + xyK*np.random.normal(0,1) #eq (11)
    if (x**2+y**2) > R**2: #if the particle is outside the boundary
        if abs(x) > R: #need to make sure arccos(x/R) is meaningful
            xn = np.sign(x)*R
            theta = np.sign(y)*np.arccos((xn/R))#angle to particle
        else:
            theta = np.sign(y)*np.arccos((x/R))#angle to particle  
        rp = np.array([x,y]) #r for the particle
        rr = np.array([np.cos(theta)*R,np.sin(theta)*R]) #r for the boundary closest to the particle
        #d = rp - rr #smallest distance from particle to boundary
        q = (2*np.linalg.norm(rr)/np.linalg.norm(rp)) - 1
        x = q*np.array(rp[0]) #x- and y-value forced inside the boundary
        y = q*np.array(rp[1])

    phiv = np.append(phiv, phi) #adding all phi-values to a vector
    xv = np.append(xv, x) # adding all x-values to a vector
    yv = np.append(yv, y) # adding all y-values to a vector'
    rv = np.append(rv,(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)))
    n=n+1 #iteration 


return(rv)
#print(rv)

for i in range(2): #run the program a number of times
    datavector = np.array(0)
    circle(1E5,1E-3,0*np.random.uniform(-1E-5,1E-5),0*np.random.uniform(-1E-5,1E-5),np.random.uniform(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi),1E-6,300,1E-3,5*1E-6,0,2E-5)
    datavector = np.append(datavector, rv)
np.savetxt('testet.txt', datavector)
```

Comment: Have you defined rv before the loop ?

Comment: And you don't have problems with that `:` on 3rd line?

Comment: Your variable `rv` is not declared somewhere in the given code. There only exists `r`, `v` and `R`. You might want to do the mean using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-average-in-python) as `datavector = np.append(datavector, mean(r, v))`

Comment: Yes, from circle(N,dt,x0,y0,phi0,r,T,nu,v,Omega,R): i get rv (I've tried printing it out). But I am not able to collect 1000 of them into an array.

Comment: I have defined rv in the function circle but not in the for i in range(1000):-loop. I want my function to give me rv

Comment: The : was a misstake from me. It isn't in the code, I've edited the post now.

Comment: My code is pretty messy so I didn't include it but my function gives me the vector rv (it has nothing to do with the argument r or v in the function, I'm just bad at naming stuff).

Comment: Gives you, how? Does it return the vector or store it in a global variable?

Comment: @xaxablyat: *I want my function to give me rv*. Then use `rv = circle(N,dt,x0,y0,phi0,r,T,nu,v,Omega,R)` and **return** it from `circle` function.

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name 'rv' is not defined` means your variable has not been defined before operations have been done upon it.

From the information you provided, `rv` is never defined. On top of that, you are re-initialising your result vector `datavector` at every iteration, while it should only be initialised BEFORE your main loop.

I assume `rv` is the return value from `circle`.

So a correction of your code should look like:

```
datavector = []
for i in range(1000):
    rv = circle(N,dt,x0,y0,phi0,r,T,nu,v,Omega,R)
    datavector.append(rv)
```

Comment: thank you, it was that i hadn't put     rv = circle(N,dt,x0,y0,phi0,r,T,nu,v,Omega,R) that was the problem! I ended up going with datav=np.ndarray(shape=(1000,1E5))
for i in range(1000): #run the program a number of times
    rv=circle(1E5,1E-3,0*np.random.uniform(-1E-5,1E-5),0*np.random.uniform(-1E-5,1E-5),np.random.uniform(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi),1E-6,300,1E-3,5*1E-6,0,2E-5)
    datav[i]=(rv)
    #print(datav)
datav=np.transpose(datav)
np.savetxt('testet.txt', datav)