# How to find mean in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

How to find mean in python

```
t = int(input("How many marks do you want entered" ))
g = 0

for i in range(t):
    c = int(input('what is your mark'))
g = c/t 
print(g)
```

I need to find the mean of all the numbers entered into c, t amount of times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating arithmetic mean (one type of average) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-one-type-of-average-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of all of the marks.  Something like:

```
t = int(input("How many marks do you want entered" ))
g = 0

marks = []
for i in range(t):
    marks.append(int(input('what is your mark')))
g = sum(marks)/t 
print(g)
```

Comment: Another possibility is keeping the running sum instead of a running list, avoiding the creation of a sequence.

Comment: @Tomothy32, yes of course.  Integrate however you will...  But Integrate you must...

Answer (score 1):

use below code:

```
t=int(input("How many marks do you want entered" ))
g=0
c=0
for i in range(t):
    c += int(input('what is your mark'))
g = c/t 
print(g)
```