# How to find maximum points between different classes (counting sorting)

Tags: python

I'm studying counting and sorting. I have a problem with this task:

> Some people participate in math competition. Winner is a person with
>   the biggest amount of points reached (winners are distributed for each
>   grade). Find the value of max points reached for each grade. In each
>   grade takes part one person or more
>
> #### INPUT
>
> Information about all participants in a file ('input.txt', for example) where each line is supposed to have this structure:
>
> ```
> family_name name grade result
> ```
>
> Family name and name should be written as a string, grades are in
>   range 10 to 12, results (points) are in range 0 to 100.
>
> #### OUTPUT
>
> Print three numbers: points of each winner of 10th, 11th and 12th grades. Inner file is supposed to be written in this way:
>
> ```
> open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
> ```

I have already solved this task but I didn't use counting sorting.
Here is full code

```py
def listAverage(list): 
    sum = 0 
    for i in list: 
        sum += i
    return sum / len(list) 
classes = []
inFile = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') 
for line in inFile: 
    grade, mark = line.split()[2:] 
    if grade in classes: 
        classes[grade].append(int(mark)) 
    else: 
        classes[grade] = [int(mark)] 
for i in range(10, 13): 
    print(listAverage(classes[str(i)]), end=' ')
```

Comment: Add this in question.

Comment: Hi pal! Add additional informations using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56360255/edit) button of the question, and not the comment section. Thank you for your understanding

Comment: @VugarSamedley what exactly is the question? Does your code have a specific issue that you need help with?

Comment: no problem with my code. i mean, i have no idea of how to solve this task using counting sotrting. that's why i am asking for help

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

- don't use variable that shadow built-in names; for example `list` should not be used, rather use `num_list` or something similar.
- you should always close files that you open. I suggest using a context manager (`with open() as f:`) to avoid forgetting to close files.
- a shorter version the calculate the average would be `sum(num_list) / len(num_list)`
  (raises error if list is empty; see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-one-type-of-average-in-python))

Here is a modified version of your code to address some issues; I also included a few suggestions (for example [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)).

Maybe this helps you (or maybe not).

```
import collections
marks_per_grade = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()             # remove newline from the end of the line

        if len(line) > 0:               # assure that the line is not empty
            last_name, first_name, grade, mark = line.split()

            # because it is a 'collections.defaultdict', if the grade does not
            # yet exist, then it will add it with an empty list as initial value
            marks_per_grade[int(grade)].append(int(mark))

for grade, mark_list in sorted(marks_per_grade.items()):
    # this will raise error if the list is empty
    avg_mark = sum(mark_list) / len(mark_list)

    print(
        '{:3d} {:3d} {:5.1f} {}'.format(
            grade,
            max(mark_list),
            avg_mark,
            mark_list))
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i've to solve this task not using any suggestions. and thx for explanations, they're great

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {10: [], 11: [], 12: []}
xxx = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
with xxx as file:
    for lines in file:

        line = lines.strip()

        firstName, name, grade, mark = line.split()

        data[int(grade)].append(int(mark))

print(data)

for grade in data:
    print(sum(data[grade])/len(data[grade]))
```