# How do you check if list is blank?

Tags: python, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: What is the best way to check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/python-what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

```
def CleanWhiteSpace(theDict):
    stuff=[]

    for key,value in theDict.items():
        for d in value:
            if value != " ":
                stuff.append(d)    
                print d
                theDict[key]=stuff
            if not value[d]:
                print value
        stuff=[]
    return theDict
    print CleanWhiteSpace({'a':['1','2'],'b':['3',' '],'c':[]})
```

I edited this because I need more help. How do you check if `c` is blank? Is `c` is simply equal to `[]`?

I've tried `==[]` and `"[]"` and getting the length and `== ""`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How do you define "blank"? Simply a list with no elements?

Comment: I (and others) actually used `if c` in the answers to your previous question.  You might learn something by studying these answers carefully.

Comment: Trying to get the length as you say was the right idea, that should have worked.

Comment: @WebMaster: If you want an question to be deleted, flag it for moderator attention and provide a good reason *why* it should be deleted.  *This* question was closed because it's a duplicate.  Please take the time to read StackOverflow's [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In python, an empty list evaluates to False.

```
if not c:
   print "The list is empty"
else:
   print "The list is not empty"
```

Comment: doesn't work             if not key:
                del theDict[key] still prints out {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': [], 'b': ['3', ' ']}