# ClearWhiteSpace, Need to check if the value is equal to []

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you check if list is blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024927/how-do-you-check-if-list-is-blank)

```
def CleanWhiteSpace(theDict) :
    stuff=[]

    for key,value in theDict.items():
        for d in value:
            if value != " ":
                stuff.append(d)    
                print d
                theDict[key]=stuff
            if not value[d]:
                print value
        stuff=[]
    return theDict
print CleanWhiteSpace({'a':['1','2'],'b':['3',' '],'c':[]})
```

how do u check is c is blank is c is simply equal to []?

okay I have a DICTIONARY that has LISTS inside it, some of these lists are composed of NOTHING. I need to loop though the dictionary and remove those keys that have the value of AN EMPTY LIST.

trying to be as clear as possible. what have i tried? i have tried multiple different methods to check if the value of the key is equal to nothing. i tried the value == "": statement, i tried the, len function to check if the value is empty, i tried if value: nothing seems to work, why? because as someone answered, empty lists don't get executed in the body of the loop

Comment: Didn't we just have this question, or is this different?

Comment: We solved the last one, this is the last question, but it has a new problem

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi nope, i got rid of that question, but some dude named sven is trying to roll it back, just to make this a possible duplicate. I asked one question, then when it was solved, edited it to something else. then edited again and created a new question. someone is constantly rolling both questions to a point where they were the same just to get me in trouble. original copies of the questions are both different.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer (and would be getting fewer votes to close it) if it made clear (1) what you mean by, e.g., "I tried `==[]`", (2) exactly what happened when you tried that, and (3) what you wanted to happen that was different. (What is your `CleanWhiteSpace` function actually supposed to do?)

Comment: I think it is hugely unlikely that anyone is doing anything "just to get you in trouble" (why on earth would they?). What actually seems to have happened is that your question got closed and you tried to delete its text with an angry message. Don't do that. It's not productive.

Comment: Also, insulting the mods is a bad way to get help. Most (all?) of the mods on SO have earned the right by patiently answering questions and making helpful edits for a substantial period of time, and have therefore built up a lot of goodwill. Insulting them is simply going to make it less likely that the community will help you :). Be nice.

Comment: like i explained, instead of making an another question, i tried to edit a solved question. then when no one was answering, i tried to make a new question. so my edit and a new question were the same. i then deleted the edited question. then someone called sven rolled back the first question, not to the original original question, but to the exact point where questions were duplicates. why didn't he roll it back to original state, but the duplicate state? just to be ill productive with ill wishes. after he did it 3 times i wrote the angry message

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi so why was this mod constantly mutilating my questions to look like duplicate's? he could have rolled the first question all the way to the begging.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan i edited my question to your specifications

Comment: Finally! Now that we know what you want to do, I've given you a solution.

Comment: It looks to me as if he simply undid your change that attempted to delete the question. If he'd noticed that you'd earlier edited an already-answered question to make it ask something different (!!!) then he might well have undone that change too, but perhaps he didn't notice. Seriously: No one is attempting to harm you here, and if you can't believe that then I'm afraid the problem is yours.

Comment: Please, name your functions not like MyFunction, but like my_function (PEP8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, when key `c` is being processed the value of `key` will be `'c'` and the value of `value` will be `[]`, an empty list. You can test for this by saying, e.g., `if not value:`. Or, if you know it's a list rather than some other kind of sequence, `if value==[]`.

It's hard to be sure from the question as written, but did you perhaps try putting something like `if d==[]:` somewhere inside the loop? That won't work, because when `value` is an empty list the loop `for d in value:` is looping over the elements of an empty list, and there aren't any, so the loop body will never be executed.

Incidentally, some other bits of your code seem to show confusion between `value` and its elements. For instance, you write `if value != " "` but surely it's `d` that you want to be testing there. And what's with `if not value[d]:`? Why would you expect `d` to be a suitable thing to index `value` by?

You should also think a bit more carefully about what happens to `stuff` as your code executes.

Comment: sigh. thank you for your explanation of why it wasn't working. so how do you make it work? how do u remove an empty list from a dictionary from an array?

Comment: I am not going to write your code for you, and most likely neither is anyone else; that isn't how Stack Overflow works. (Aside from anything else, for all we know this is some kind of homework assignment and solving it for you would make it harder for you to learn.) You need to be more specific about what it is you want to know.

Comment: Incidentally, note that both I and Chinmay *did* say how to do it right: the usual way to check whether a list is empty is to say something like `if not value:`. If for some reason this doesn't work for you, *show us how it fails* and then maybe we can help further.

Comment: I agree with Gareth. "they don't work in this specific snippet that i have" is not helpful. We can't fix code that isn't there.

Comment: What part is confusing? gareth said, since the variable value is empty, the emptiness doesn't get pulled through the main loop. How do you delete empty lists from the dictionary?  what do you guys need me to explain? {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': [], 'b': ['3', ' ']}
 here is how it fails. key c has the value of "[]". key c is not supposed to exist. and the code is already written. it just doesn't work

Comment: found solution, ty for trying +1

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

How about this?

```
def CleanWhiteSpace(theDict):
    newDict = {}
    for key in theDict:
        if theDict[key]:
            newDict[key] = theDict[key]
    return newDict
```

Note that this avoids modifying `theDict` in place, so if you want that, just ask.

<strike>There are two ways to check if a list is blank:</strike>

```
a_list = []
if not a_list:
    do something #the if is entered if the list is blank
```

Or

```
a_list = []
if len(a_list)==0:
    do something
```

The two snippets are equivalent. Note that the first one works because the value of `a_list` is implicitly converted to a boolean and `bool([])` is `False`.

Comment: they don't work in this specific snippet that i have, i don't know why

Comment: Where in the code are you testing for the empty list? Show us that code.

Comment: its all there. the code is being executed form print statement print CleanWhiteSpace({'a':['1','2'],'b':['3',' '],'c':[]})

Comment: okay.. how does this delete empty spaces? and its all good i found a solution +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
theDict = dict( [(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v)>0])
```

Comment: Change that to `theDict = dict( [(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if v)`. It's more Pythonic.