# What is a None value?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I have been studying Python, and I read a chapter which describes the `None` value, but unfortunately this book isn't very clear at some points. I thought that I would find the answer to my question, if I share it there.

I want to know what the `None` value *is* and what do you use it for?

And also, I don't get this part of the book:

> Assigning a value of `None` to a variable is one way to reset it to
>   its original, empty state.

What does that mean?

The answers were great, although I didn't understand most of answers due to my low knowledge of the computer world (I haven't learned about classes, objects, etc.). What does this sentence mean?

> Assigning a value of `None` to a variable is one way to reset it
>   to its original, empty state.

Final:

Finally I've got my answer from looking to different answers. I must appreciate all the people who put their times to help me (especially Martijn Pieters and DSM), and I wish that I could choose all answers as the best, but the selection is limited to one. All of the answers were great.

Comment: That book isn't too helpful; `None` is not a default empty state for variables.

Comment: Off the top of my head php is the only language whose null value is equivalent to the default empty state for a variable. Now I'm wondering what other languages do that.

Comment: @kojiro perl, though neither of the equality operators are happy about comparing to `undef`.  also arguably javascript, though it has both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @kojiro javascript variable's default value is `undefined`, if left uninitialized.

Comment: Right, which is *different* from `null`, a point I'm failing to make to @MartijnPieters in his answer.

Comment: @kojiro: I merely meant to include *brief* examples of other examples of similar flag values in other contexts; trying to avoid going into too much detail. This is a Python answer after all. In any case, I updated it to mention both null and undefined with a link that explains the difference. I'll leave it at that, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's all I really wanted. :) but I'm beginning to realize someone could write an academic paper on the definition of *emptiness* varying on type strictness and binding rules.

Comment: Exactly, and this is not the place for it and I am not going to write it. :-P

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Martijn's answer explains what `None` is in Python, and correctly states that the book is misleading.  Since Python programmers as a rule would never say

> Assigning a value of `None` to a variable is one way to reset it to
>   its original, empty state.

it's hard to explain what Briggs means in a way which makes sense and explains why no one here seems happy with it.  One analogy which may help:

In Python, variable names are like stickers put on objects.  Every sticker has a unique name written on it, and it can only be on one object at a time, but you could put more than one sticker on the same object, if you wanted to.  When you write

```
F = "fork"
```

you put the sticker "F" on a string object `"fork"`.  If you then write

```
F = None
```

you move the sticker to the `None` object.

What Briggs is asking you to imagine is that you didn't **write** the sticker `"F"`, there was *already* an `F` sticker on the `None`, and all you did was **move** it, from `None` to `"fork"`.  So when you type `F = None`, you're "reset[ting] it to its original, empty state", if we decided to treat `None` as meaning `empty state`.

I can see what he's getting at, but that's a bad way to look at it.  If you start Python and type `print(F)`, you see

```
>>> print(F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'F' is not defined
```

and that `NameError` means Python doesn't recognize the name `F`, **because there is no such sticker**.  If Briggs were right and `F = None` resets `F` to its original state, then it should be there now, and we should see

```
>>> print(F)
None
```

like we do after we type `F = None` and put the sticker on `None`.

---

So that's all that's going on.  In reality, Python comes with some stickers already attached to objects (built-in names), but others you have to write yourself with lines like `F = "fork"` and `A = 2` and `c17 = 3.14`, and then you can stick them on other objects later (like `F = 10` or `F = None`; it's all the same.)

Briggs is pretending that all possible stickers you might want to write were already stuck to the `None` object.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by Briggs?are you referring to the author of this book?because his name is Jason R. Briggs.

Comment: @The_Diver: yep, that's him.

Comment: Where can i find more info about Python's built-in names?thanks.

Comment: This is a great explanation for a non-programmer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 73):

`None` is just a value that commonly is used to signify 'empty', or 'no value here'. It is a *signal object*; it only has meaning because the Python documentation says it has that meaning.

There is only one copy of that object in a given Python interpreter session.

If you write a function, and that function doesn't use an explicit `return` statement, `None` is returned instead, for example. That way, programming with functions is much simplified; a function **always** returns *something*, even if it is only that one `None` object.

You can test for it explicitly:

```
if foo is None:
    # foo is set to None

if bar is not None:
    # bar is set to something *other* than None
```

Another use is to give optional parameters to functions an 'empty' default:

```
def spam(foo=None):
    if foo is not None:
        # foo was specified, do something clever!
```

The function `spam()` has a optional argument; if you call `spam()` without specifying it, the default value `None` is given to it, making it easy to detect if the function was called with an argument or not.

Other languages have similar concepts. SQL has `NULL`; JavaScript has [`undefined` *and* `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined), etc.

Note that in Python, variables exist by virtue of being used. You don't need to declare a variable first, so there are no really *empty* variables in Python. Setting a variable to `None` is then not the same thing as setting it to a default empty value; `None` is a value too, albeit one that is often used to *signal* emptyness. The book you are reading is misleading on that point.

Comment: I think the semantics of *emptiness* are different from those of *undefinedness*. So I'm not sure the JavaScript and SQL counterparts are clarifying - they may confuse the issue. JavaScript has both `undefined` *and* `null`.

Comment: @kojiro: `undefined` is an object in JavaScript, and you can use that object explicitly just like you can use `None` in Python. It is a signal object, with much the same meaning.

Comment: @kojiro: SQL is not a programming language, but `NULL` is still something that can be assigned and tested for explicitly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: SQL *is* a programming language, just a very specific purpose, declarative one.

Comment: @daniel: wether SQL qualifies as a programming language has been a long debate... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900055/is-sql-or-even-tsql-turing-complete for interesting angles.

Answer (score 26):

This is what the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) has got to say about `None`:

> The sole value of types.NoneType. None is frequently used to represent
>   the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a
>   function.
>
> Changed in version 2.4: Assignments to None are illegal and raise a
>   SyntaxError.
>
> Note The names None and **debug** cannot be reassigned (assignments to
>   them, even as an attribute name, raise SyntaxError), so they can be
>   considered “true” constants.

1. Let's confirm the type of `None` first

   ```
   print type(None)
   print None.__class__
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   <type 'NoneType'>
   <type 'NoneType'>
   ```

Basically, `NoneType` is a data type just like `int`, `float`, etc. You can check out the list of default types available in Python in *[8.15. types — Names for built-in types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#module-types)*.

2. And, `None` is an instance of `NoneType` class. So we might want to create instances of `None` ourselves. Let's try that

   ```
   print types.IntType()
   print types.NoneType()
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   0
   TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances
   ```

So clearly, cannot create `NoneType` instances. We don't have to worry about the uniqueness of the value `None`.

3. Let's check how we have implemented `None` internally.

   ```
   print dir(None)
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', 
    '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
    '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
   ```

Except `__setattr__`, all others are read-only attributes. So, there is no way we can alter the attributes of `None`.

4. Let's try and add new attributes to `None`

   ```
   setattr(types.NoneType, 'somefield', 'somevalue')
   setattr(None, 'somefield', 'somevalue')
   None.somefield = 'somevalue'
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'NoneType'
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'somefield'
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'somefield'
   ```

The above seen statements produce these error messages, respectively. It means that, we cannot create attributes dynamically on a `None` instance.

5. Let us check what happens when we assign something `None`. As per the documentation, it should throw a `SyntaxError`. It means, if we assign something to `None`, the program will not be executed at all.

   ```
   None = 1
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   SyntaxError: cannot assign to None
   ```

We have established that

1. `None` is an instance of `NoneType`
2. `None` cannot have new attributes
3. Existing attributes of `None` cannot be changed.
4. We cannot create other instances of `NoneType`
5. We cannot even change the reference to `None` by assigning values to it.

So, as mentioned in the documentation, `None` can really be considered as a `true constant`.

Happy knowing `None` :)

Comment: Very very interesting!! one doubt what is use of `__setattr__` for None

Answer (score 12):

[The book](http://goo.gl/sCdG2J) you refer to is clearly trying to *greatly* simplify the meaning of `None`. Python variables don't *have* an initial, empty state – Python variables are [bound (only) when they're defined](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html). You can't create a Python variable without giving it a value.

```
>>> print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> def test(x):
...   print(x)
... 
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: test() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
>>> def test():
...   print(x)
... 
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

but sometimes you want to make a function mean different things depending on whether a variable is defined or not. You can create an argument with a default value of `None`:

```
>>> def test(x=None):
...   if x is None:
...     print('no x here')
...   else:
...     print(x)
... 
>>> test()
no x here
>>> test('x!')
x!
```

The fact that this value is the special `None` value is not terribly important in this case. I could've used any default value:

```
>>> def test(x=-1):
...   if x == -1:
...     print('no x here')
...   else:
...     print(x)
... 
>>> test()
no x here
>>> test('x!')
x!
```

…but having `None` around gives us two benefits:

1. We don't have to pick a special value like `-1` whose meaning is unclear, and
2. Our function may actually need to handle `-1` as a normal input.

```python
>>> test(-1)
no x here
```

oops!

So the book is a little misleading mostly in its use of the word *reset* – assigning `None` to a name is a signal to a programmer that that value isn't being used or that the function should behave in some default way, but to *reset* a value to its original, undefined state you must use the `del` keyword:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> x
3
>>> del x
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 7):

Other answers have already explained meaning of ***None*** beautifully. However, I would still like to throw more light on this using an example.

**Example:**

```
def extendList(val, list=[]):
    list.append(val)
    return list

list1 = extendList(10)
list2 = extendList(123,[])
list3 = extendList('a')

print "list1 = %s" % list1
print "list2 = %s" % list2
print "list3 = %s" % list3
```

Now try to guess output of above list. Well, ***the answer*** is surprisingly as below:

```
list1 = [10, 'a']
list2 = [123]
list3 = [10, 'a']
```

---

**But Why?**

Many will mistakenly expect *list1* to be equal to *[10]* and *list3* to be equal to *['a']*, thinking that the list argument will be set to its default value of *[]* each time extendList is called.

However, what actually happens is that **the new default list is created only once when the function is defined**, and that same list is then used subsequently whenever extendList is invoked without a list argument being specified. This is because **expressions in default arguments are calculated when the function is defined, not when it’s called**.

*list1* and *list3* are therefore operating on the same default list, whereas *list2* is operating on a separate list that it created (by passing its own empty list as the value for the list parameter).

---

**'None' the savior: (Modify example above to produce desired behavior)**

```
def extendList(val, list=None):
    if list is None:
       list = []
    list.append(val)
    return list

list1 = extendList(10)
list2 = extendList(123,[])
list3 = extendList('a')

print "list1 = %s" % list1
print "list2 = %s" % list2
print "list3 = %s" % list3
```

With this revised implementation, the output would be:

```
list1 = [10]
list2 = [123]
list3 = ['a']
```

*Note* - Example credit to toptal.com

Answer (score 6):

> None is a singleton object (meaning there is only one None), used in many places in the language and library to **represent the absence of some value**.

**For example:**
 if `d` is a dictionary, `d.get(k)` will return `d[k]` if it exists, but `None` if `d` has no key `k`.

Read this info from a great blog: https://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html

Comment: this is the only useful answer

Answer (score 3):

All of these are good answers but I think there's more to explain why `None` is useful.

Imagine you collecting RSVPs to a wedding. You want to record whether each person will attend. If they are attending, you set `person.attending = True`. If they are not attending you set `person.attending = False`. If you have not received any RSVP, then `person.attending = None`. That way you can distinguish between no information - `None` - and a negative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I love code examples (as well as fruit), so let me show you

```
apple = "apple"
print(apple)
>>> apple
apple = None
print(apple)
>>> None
```

None means nothing, it has no value.

None evaluates to False.

Comment: `print(None)` prints.. `None`. It does **not**, as you suggest, print nothing.

Comment: the REPL only shows nothing for `None` if it's the result of the last expression.  (which is mostly helpful for functions not intended to return a value.)

Comment: Eugh, my mistake, I was using IDLE and I assumed it printed variables, apparently it uses repl. I'm currently using SO to perfect my own python/javascript/code reading & understanding skills, so I'm making some mistakes :(

Comment: IDLE, like the Python interactive interpreter prompt, explicitly *hides* `None` if that is the result of an expression, mostly to not clutter up the output.

Answer (score -5):

```
largest=none
smallest =none 
While True :
          num =raw_input ('enter a number ') 
          if num =="done ": break 
          try :
           inp =int (inp) 
          except:
              Print'Invalid input' 
           if largest is none :
               largest=inp
           elif inp>largest:
                largest =none 
           print 'maximum', largest

          if smallest is none:
               smallest =none
          elif inp<smallest :
               smallest =inp
          print 'minimum', smallest 

print 'maximum, minimum, largest, smallest
```