# Simple binary tree in python

Tags: python

So I'm using the binary tree class to build trees
I'm making simple trees but can't figure out why I keep getting errors

```
class BinaryTree:

def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

def insert_left(self, new_data):
    if self.left == None:
        self.left = BinaryTree(new_data)
    else:
        t = BinaryTree(new_data)
        t.left = self.left
        self.left = t

def insert_right(self, new_data):
    if self.right == None:
        self.right = BinaryTree(new_data)
    else:
        t = BinaryTree(new_data)
        t.right = self.right
        self.right = t

def get_left(self):
    return self.left

def get_right(self):
    return self.right

def set_data(self, data):
    self.data = data

def get_data(self):
    return self.data
```

I have the code above but can't figure out how to implement it to get a tree like this
[image]

I've tried running it through 
`def create_a_tree():
    tree=BinaryTree('a')
    tree.insert_left('b')
    tree.insert_right('c')
    return(tree)`

But this doesn't work

Comment: Please be more specific about what "doesn't work." Also, your code is not formatted correctly `__init__` and so should the rest of the methods. It is hard to figure out the problem without actually seeing what your code looks like.

Comment: Have you indented everything correctly? I ran your code through your example and it seems to be working just fine after I fixed indentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that seem slightly off with your code.

One thing is that the code doesn't seem properly indented. Indentation has a syntactic and semantic value in Python, so if you want your methods to be *inside* the class you must indent as in

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

The second thing I can see is that you're checking for `None` using `==`, whereas the correct way of doing that is `if x is None` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19473207/5474844) and [here](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html) for details).

As a side note: Unlike Java, Python doesn't really need getters and setters, as classes and most objects can be modified at runtime. So instead of declaring a method like `set_data`, you can simply set `bt.data=your_data` on a `BinaryTree` object.