# Pyscripter: How do I use if statements with an undefined variable?

Tags: python, if-statement, undefined, statements

This is the part of my code i need help with:

```
if done==0 or done== undefined:
    print("Good job!")
```

I made another "If" statement earlier where I give "done" a value, but if it was not given a value, (there is no input) and i want the code to be "if 'done' is 0, or 'done' is undefined" do what ever, for example print "Good job!" if it 'done' 0 or undefined

Is there a way I could do this? Any help would be very much appreciated!

My question has been solved. Thank you to everyone who answered!

Comment: initialize your variable with `done = 0`.

Comment: Use `None` instead of `undefined`, unless you have defined your `undefined` variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best, most pythonic way is to initialize `done` at the very beginning to something that is clearly meaningless. Then you can test for that meaninglessness. The pythonic way is

```
done = None
```

where `None` is a special value that means nothing meaningful. In other words, that is (or can be) Python for "undefined." After that is done, you may assign `done` to zero in some circumstances. You would then later test

```
if done == 0 or done is None:
    print("Good job!")
```

For more about `None`, see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473185/what-is-a-none-value).

If you really, really must leave `done` completely undefined and then test for that, you can use an exception. But I don't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You should use None instead of undefined.

```
if done == 0 or done is None:
    print(Good job!)
```

Answer (score 0):

The None value is as close to an 'undefined' as you can get. Set the initial value of done to be None then you can test for:

```
if done == 0 or done is None
```