# Better way to create a new column based on values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

What is a better way to create the same column mentioned below:

```
col_new = []
for r1 in df['col_A']:
    if r1==1:
        for r2 in df['col_B']:
            if r2!='None':
                col_new.append('col_new')

df['col_new'] = col_new
```

My dataframe is huge (120k * 22) and running the above code is hanging the notebook. Is there a faster and more efficient way to create this column where it represents all the non-null values of col_B when col_A is 1.

Comment: Do provide us with a sample data `few rows` and your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need to create boolean mask and then append value by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = (df['col_A'] == 1) & (df['col_B']!='None')

#if None is not string
#mask = (df['col_A'] == 1) & (df['col_B'].notnull())
df.loc[mask, 'col_new'] = 'col_new'
```

**Sample**:

In column are strings `None`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_A': [1,1,2,1],
    'col_B': ['a','None','None','a']
})
print (df)
   col_A col_B
0      1     a
1      1  None
2      2  None
3      1     a

mask = (df['col_A'] == 1) & (df['col_B']!='None')
df.loc[mask, 'col_new'] = 'val'
print (df)
   col_A col_B col_new
0      1     a     val
1      1  None     NaN
2      2  None     NaN
3      1     a     val
```

In column are [not strings `None`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19473207), then use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_A': [1,1,2,1],
    'col_B': ['a',None,None,'a']
})
print (df)
   col_A col_B
0      1     a
1      1  None
2      2  None
3      1     a

mask = (df['col_A'] == 1) & (df['col_B'].notna())
#oldier pandas versions
#mask = (df['col_A'] == 1) & (df['col_B'].notnull())
df.loc[mask, 'col_new'] = 'val'
print (df)
   col_A col_B col_new
0      1     a     val
1      1  None     NaN
2      2  None     NaN
3      1     a     val
```

Also if want use `if-else` statement [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is really helpfull:

```
df['col_new'] = np.where(mask, 'val', 'another_val')
print (df)
   col_A col_B      col_new
0      1     a          val
1      1  None  another_val
2      2  None  another_val
3      1     a          val
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for.