# Python MySQL - inserting null values

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to insert values into a table.

eg:

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO info( id, Diet ) VALUES( %s, %s)"
values = [
    (1, ??? ),
    (2, "Low carb diet"),
    (3, "nut allergy"),
```

Item 1 currently has no information but this could change in the future.

I have tried using "NULL" - this doesn't create a null value it is a string (beginner mistakes :/)

Trying to insert null without quotations classes as an unresolved reference.

Leaving the field empty produces the following

```
line 329, in _batch_insert
"Failed executing the operation; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters
```

i could insert data one at a time, but id like to know if there was an alternative?

Comment: Use the corresponding Python value, [`None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473185/what-is-a-none-value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code

```
values = [
    (1, None ),
    (2, "Low carb diet"),
    (3, "nut allergy"),
```

Comment: Appreciated mate