# none type object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to replace `None` with `0` but I'm getting an error as none type object has no attribute 'replace'. This is what I have tried

views.py:

```
def Activity(UserID):

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivityAudit] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
        result_set =cursor.fetchall()
        data = []
        for row in result_set:
         
            TaskId = row[0]
            data.append({
            'TaskId':row[0],           
            'TaskName' : row[1],
            'Source' : row[2],
            'Requester' : row[3].replace('None', '0') if row[3] == None else row[3] ,
            'type' : row[4],
            'IsActive':GetCurrentSubTaskSTatus(TaskId),
   
            })
        
            print(data)  
            return Response(data[0], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: `'0' if row[3] is None else row[3]`

Answer (score 1):

```
row[3].replace('None', '0') if row[3] == None else row[3]
```

Reflect about it:

```
if row[3] == None:
    row[3].replace('None', '0')
```

If `row[3]` is `None`, how can it be a `str`ing? And how can it contain `'None'`?

---

You should replace that part with the following:

```
'0' if row[3] == None else row[3]
```

---

To better understand your problem, I would suggest you to read the following:

- [What is a None value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473185/what-is-a-none-value)
- [None in CPython](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp)

Comment: @johnraj if it worked for you please accept my answer, otherwise feel free to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

replace is a method for strings. None is not string, it is NoneType object.

You can try following code for your case:

```
'Requester' : row[3] or '0',
```

It will use value of row[3] if it is not None. Otherwise it will use '0'

Comment: if you want to use ternary then try this::     'Requester': row[3] if row[3] is not None else '0'