# Omit data types when inserting Pandas data frame to SQL Server table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am loading data from Excel to a SQL Server table. All SQL table columns data types set to `nvarvar`.

In case I have "na" or empty cells, I am setting them to 'NULL' values in Pandas as below:

```
df=df.fillna("NULL")
```

It inserts some of the rows but it is failing on some, error message is below:

> SQL Server Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'NULL' to data type int.

Any ideas how I could address this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) use None instead of the string "Null".

[image]

Comment: Bwone, My insert goes little further with this one but still fails for some records. "Conversion falied when converting the nvarchar value "None" to data type int error

Comment: None, not "None". See eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473185/what-is-a-none-value