# why the NULL value handling not working properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a simple code to handle null value for string type column and float type column as shown below:

```
def format_item(item):
    if item is None:
        if isinstance(item, (Decimal, float)):
            return 0.00
        else:
            return ""
    else:
        if isinstance(item, (Decimal, float)):
            return float(item)
        else:
            return str(item)
```

Above code is suppose to handle `NULL` values in both `string type column` and `float type column`. i.e. if there is a NULL in float type column, then it is suppose to replace it with 0.00 in the output, and similarly, if there is a NULL in string type column, so it should return "", i.e. empty string.

Below is the output as seen my logs, and if 3rd list is seen, the the `2nd last element` is shown there as a empty string, i.e. `""`. However, if I go with the logic from the above code, it should have been 0 at least if not 0.00.

```
['681738eb', 'Agi', '6817-abc', '5280-oou', 'xyz', 'ert', 'yuo', 'test1', 'garbage', 13456.76, 16148.12, 2691.36, '2023-11-30 16:16:38']
['681738eb', 'Agi', '6817-abc', '5280-oou', 'xyz', 'ert', 'yuo', 'test1', 'garbage', 13456.76, 16148.12, 13.92, '2023-12-01 08:48:33']
['681738eb', 'Agi', '6817-abc', '5280-oou', 'xyz', 'ert', 'yuo', 'test1', 'garbage', 13456.76, 16148.12,  '', '2023-11-30 16:17:14']
```

As seen in my DB, the data type of that column is `"Double"`

Above function have been called in the below function.

```
def stored_procedure_call(SP_name, id, entity):
    logging.info(f"Fetching DB connection details.")
    try:
        # Load env file
        load_dotenv()
        # Create the connection object
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=os.getenv('USER_NAME'),
            password=get_db_password(os.getenv('RDS_HOST')),
            host=os.getenv('RDS_HOST'),
            database=os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
            port=os.getenv('PORT'))

        # Create a cursor
        cursor = conn.cursor()
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error("An unexpected error occurred: {}".format(error))

    try:

        # Call the stored procedure with the provided ID
        cursor.callproc(SP_name, [id, entity])
        conn.commit()

        result_list = []
        for result in cursor.stored_results():
            rows = result.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                result_list.append(list(row))
                logging.info(row)

        if not result_list:
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps([])
            }

        result_list_serializable = [list(format_item(item) for item in tup) for tup in result_list]

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'body': json.dumps(result_list_serializable)
        }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: In the `item is None` branch of your code, how could `isinstance(item, (Decimal, float))` possibly be true?  You *know* what type `item` is at that point - it's `NoneType`.

Comment: Ok, so can you please suggest the changes in the code?

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would convert empty strings to anything...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the string is empty in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python) also see: [What is a None value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473185/what-is-a-none-value) and [Null object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

the one problem that I see is that, if you have item as None your condition:

```
if isinstance(item, (Decimal, float))
```

will always be False (because None is not an instance of any of those), so you will go directly to your else statement, therefore return "".

What I can suggest is to add argument to your function with default type and value provided based on the column you are considering, like that:

```
DEFAULTS = {
    'col_a': (float, 0.0),
    'col_b': (str, "")
}

def format_item(item, default):
    if item is None:
        return default[1]
    else:
        return default[0](items)
```

Comment: Going to implement, will see if that works.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this. I have passed float on the function call. But it giving same result as before.

Comment: `isinstance(item_type, (Decimal, float))` this doesn't work. If the caller passes `float` for the type, the function is checking `isinstance(float, (Decimal, float))` which is false.
Instead, have the function take a default value and have `if item is None: return default`

Comment: You are right, I've changed my answer, please try this approach

Answer (score 0):

If item is None  - it can't be an instance of Decimal, float or str. It has type NoneType.

`print(type(None))`

yields:

<class 'NoneType'>

```
def format_item(item):
    return None if item is None \
    elif isinstance(item, (Decimal, float)) return float(item) \
    else return str(item)
```

You can choose to opt for a default of one or the other - empty string or 0.00 depending on your preference.. so that could alternatively be the first return value if item is None.

There are only 3 possible return branches - not 4!