# python: how to determine if multidimensional array is empy, and value error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm initializing an array like this:

```
import numpy as np
g = np.array([no_classes, no_features, no_classes])
```

`no_classes` and `no_features` are both integers, let's say they equal 2 and 3 respectively. So I intend to make `g` a 3D array of shape (2,3,2).

Later on, I calculate a 2D array called `temp_g` that has shape: (`no_features`, `no_classes`).

Now, within a loop, I want to assign the ***j*** th element of `g` with `temp_g` if `g` hasn't been assigned anything yet, otherwise I want to add `temp_g` to it using simple matrix addition.

```
  if g[j] is []: #  <-- is this the correct way to determine if g is empty?
      g[j] = curr_g                          
  else:
      g[j] = g[j] + curr_g
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Minor comment: to check if g[j] contains an array you could use either `if len(g[j])` (for all kind of arrays) or `if g[j].any()` (for numpy arrays)

Comment: I tried `if len(g[j]) == 0` but it gave me this error: `TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()`. Why is it taking `g[j]` to be a single value when `g` is a 3D array and so `g[j]` ought to be a 2D array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use `is` to compare if two objects are equal, use `==` instead:

> ```
> In [110]: [] is []
> Out[110]: False
>
> In [111]: []==[]
> Out[111]: True
> ```

- Your `g` is a 1D numpy array, and `g[j]` gets you an element, whilst `curr_g` might be an array. To reproduce your error:

> ```
> In [117]: l=np.arange(3)
>      ...: l[0]=[1,2] #assigning an element of a numpy array to as a python list
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-117-817e72d77bd0> in <module>()
>       1 l=np.arange(3)
> ----> 2 l[0]=[1,2]
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
> ```

- `np.array([no_classes, no_features, no_classes])` gives you a **1D** array of length 3. If you want to initialize `g` as a 3D array of shape `(no_classes, no_features, no_classes)`, use `np.zeros`, e.g.:

> ```
> In [124]: np.zeros((2,3,2))
> Out[124]: 
> array([[[ 0.,  0.],
>         [ 0.,  0.],
>         [ 0.,  0.]],
>
>        [[ 0.,  0.],
>         [ 0.,  0.],
>         [ 0.,  0.]]])
> ```

- To check if a subarray of `g` is unassigned(namely, all are 0s here IIUC), use `np.allclose`:

> ```
> In [128]: l=np.zeros((2,3,2))
>
> In [129]: np.allclose(l[0], 0)
> Out[129]: True
> ```

Comment: `g` is not 1D, I initialized it at the beginning to be 3D: `g = np.array([no_classes, no_features, no_classes])`, so shouldn't `g[j]` be a 2D array?

Comment: @user961627 is `no_classes` a number or a list/array?

Comment: `no_classes` and `no_features` are both simple integers. So if they respectively equal 2 and 3, then my intention was to make `g` a 3D array of the following dimensions: 2x3x2. Maybe I'm initializing it wrong?

Comment: Thanks! But now how do I check if it's been assigned a value or not? I can't use `[]` any more, nor can I test if `len(g[j]) == 0` because now the length will never be 0... Same problem with using the `size` attribute. So how can I test for it being unassigned any value?

Answer (score 1):

In Python `is` checks for object identity, so whether to objects are actually the same.

```
>>>a=[]
>>>a is []
False
>>>
```

So `g[j] is []` is never `True`.
As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295609/how-can-i-check-whether-the-numpy-array-is-empty-or-not) you could check the `size` attribute.