# matlab isempty() function in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code in matlab:

```
switch 1
    case isempty(A) 
...
```

where A is a 2 dimension Array.

How can I check with numpy if a 2-dim Array is empty (only has 0 values)?

Comment: This is quite a late comment but I just came to this question trying to translate some matlab code to python. There is a wrong assumption in the question (at least for nowadays way of functioning matlab): `isempty()` does NOT check for 'only contains zeros' but for 'at least on dimension is length zero' (), meaning A has no content. Thus the answer is rather `A.size == 0` as posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295609/how-can-i-check-whether-the-numpy-array-is-empty-or-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can compare your array `x`, with 0 and see if all values are False

`np.all(x==0)`

Answer (score 10):

For checking if an array is empty (that is, it doesn't contain any elements), you can use `A.size == 0`:

```
import numpy as np
In [2]: A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: A.size
Out[3]: 4

In [4]: B = np.array([[], []])

In [5]: B.size
Out[5]: 0
```

To check whether it only contains 0's you can check for `np.count_nonzero(A)`:

```
In [13]: Y = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
In [14]: np.count_nonzero(Y)
Out[14]: 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the matlab code is trying to find out with isempty() if the array only includes 0. So size would not work I guess. So I try your second one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> empty_array = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> empty_array
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> if np.all(empty_array==0): print True
... 
True
>>> empty_array[1][1]=1
>>> empty_array
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> if np.all(empty_array==0): 
...    print True
... else:
...    print False
... 
False
```