# Check if list or array element is empty

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I know how to check if a list is empty ([Best way to check if a list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty?rq=1)) and how to check if a `numpy` array is empty ([How can I check whether the numpy array is empty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295609/how-can-i-check-whether-the-numpy-array-is-empty-or-not))

I have an element that can be at times a list, and other times an array. I need to check whether this element is empty, without knowing beforehand which one it is. I can think of doing

```
if isinstance(a, list):
    if a:
        # do something
elif a.any():
    # do something
```

But I wonder if there might be a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Is the code for a list and an array identical?

Comment: Yes, the same code is executed if the element is not empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`size`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html#numpy.ndarray.size) attribute.

```
a = np.asarray(a)  # converts it to an array if it's not an array.
if a.size == 0:
    # it's empty!
```

This works also for lists because of the `np.asarray`. You haven't specified what you want to do if it's not empty but given that you allow `numpy.ndarray`s it's likely the operations will convert it to an array anyway so you won't have much overhead with the `np.asarray`-call

If you really don't want the overhead of `np.asarray`:

```
if not getattr(a, 'size', len(a)):  # However this does not work on numpy scalars
    # it's empty
```

Comment: I like the second solution :)

Comment: I suspect the OP isn't concerned with 'scalar' arrays.  I rarely deal with those; and if I did, I wouldn't be asking if it was empty.  So the `len(a)` answer might quite useful.

Comment: I don't doubt that but `np.asarray` (or `np.asanyarray` when subclasses should pass through) is in my view the "most pythonic approach". At least if numpy functions are used on `a` they will cast it to an array anyway.