# testing if an array is not empty in numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.1])
assert a!=[]
```

this returned false. Why is this the case? How do I check an array is non-empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `[]` is an empty Python `list` object, while `np.array([0.1])` is a numpy array. You can't really compare the two as you have done; a better way would be to access the `size` property of the numpy array (also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295609/how-can-i-check-whether-the-numpy-array-is-empty-or-not)).

```
a = np.array([0.1])
assert a.size != 0
```

Comment: Does `len(a)` returns the same as `a.size` ? It would then be convenient to use interchangeably for input lists or input arrays.

Comment: The only case in which `len(a)` will return the same result as `a.size` is in the case of single-dimensional arrays, where the length is the same as the number of elements in the array. For example, if `z = np.zeros(shape=(10))`, then `len(z)` and `z.size` return the same value. However, in the case of `...shape=(100,10,10)...`, `len(z)` would return the same value as `z.shape[0]`, or the first shape dimension. `z.size` would return `100 * 10 * 10`.

Comment: `a.size > 0` would save you a keystroke :-)