# Multiple outcomes from numpy where statement

Tags: python, numpy

I have an excel sheet that has 4 column, (Column 1,2,3,4).

The data in the columns is binary 1 or 0. however, sometimes in the column there are X's. when an X appears in one row of a column, it will appear at that row over all columns.

What i am trying to do is to sum all the columns across by rows and attribute a Pass, Fail or X status.

Max sum across the rows can be 4, if it is 4 it is a Fail.
If it is less than 4 its a pass.
If it is an X i want it to remain as an X in the new df created

```
What i have done is:
criteria = df['Column 1'] + df['Column 2'] + df['Column 3 '] + df['Column 4']
df['criteria'] = np.where(criteria == 4, 'Fail', 'Pass')
```

The problem is that this marks the Xs as a pass.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the code you are *adding* all the values.
This won't work as you intend because all the values may be strings, or worse, a combination of ints and strings.
This will either return a string, or raise a `TypeError`.

Hereafter, the values of `df['Column 1']`, `df['Column 2']`, `df['Column 3']`, `df['Column 4']` are considered strings. (you may have to convert them to strings, if they are not already)

First, find 'X' in the `df` columns, and set `df['criteria']` to `'X'` if it does.

Second, convert the strings to numbers and add the numbers, and then do the comparison with 4.

Use this:

```py
# make `np.array` of the concerned columns
slice = np.array((
    df['Column 1'], df['Column 2'], df['Column 3'], df['Column 4']
))

# `slice` is a transpose of `df`, so transpose again to make it same
slice = np.transpose(slice)

for i in range(len(slice)):
    row = slice[i]
    if np.array(np.where(row == 'X')).size > 0:
        df['criteria'][i] = 'X'
    else:
        row = row.astype('int')
        if sum(row) == 4:
            df['criteria'][i] = 'Fail'
        elif sum(row) < 4:
            df['criteria'][i] = 'Pass'
```

**NOTES:**

- This assumes that a column named 'criteria' already exists and has the appropriate size to store all the values.
- For more information about the first `if` statement in the `for` loop (line 11), see [How can I check whether a numpy array is empty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295609/#11295857)
- This code was tested with the following value of `df`

  ```py
  # Note: This `DataFrame` looks different.
  # Note: The columns are horizontal instead of vertical
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={
      'Column 1': ['0', '1', 'X', '1'],
      'Column 2': ['1', '1', 'X', '1'],
      'Column 3': ['0', '1', 'X', '0'],
      'Column 4': ['0', '1', 'X', '1'],
      'Expected': ['Pass', 'Fail', 'X', 'Pass'],
      'criteria': ['', '', '', '']
  }, dtype='str')
  ```

  And the expected result (`df['Expected']`) matched  `df['criteria']`

Comment: Have you tested this? I expect it will throw errors.

Comment: @fountainhead, yes I have. I provided some notes about it as well.