# Phython - While loop for a list until it is empty

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, while-loop

I was trying to write the following code:

```
def ordering(n):
    eqvec=np.zeros(n)
    bvec=[]
    for i in range(n):
        eqvec[i]=orderingeq(n,i+1)
    while eqvec:
        index_max=np.argmax(eqvec)
        bvec.append(index_max)
        eqvec.remove(index_max)
    return bvec
```

In this code I have two vectors. The first vector 'eqvec' contains some numbers which are determined with the equation 'orderingeq'. From this point I need to fill the vector 'bvec' with the index values of maximum of the vector 'eqvec'. From what I have found online is that this should work, or at least I have not found an alternate way to do this. But I get the error message corresponding to the line 'while eqvec:'.

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Could someone help me by telling me what is wrong with my code and maybe tell me how it should be done?

Comment: Use a list instead of a numpy array and it will work.

Comment: I think so, from what I understand I should write 'while eqvec.any():'. Now I don't get the error anymore

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295609/how-can-i-check-whether-a-numpy-array-is-empty-or-not) is the correct way to check whether a numpy array is empty or not. Try:

```
while eqvec.size != 0:
```

Be aware that if `eqvec` is a list instead of a numpy array this doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I think `bvec = np.flip(np.argsort(eqvec))` would give you what you need. `np.argsort(eqvec)` would give you an array of the index locations, starting from smallest to largest, and then `np.flip` would reverse the index locations so instead your position of the largest element is first, second largest is second etc.

If you'd rather the result be a in a list then you can just pass that into `list`.