# Boolean testing a list in Python

Tags: python, list, boolean

I was testing a list to see if it's empty or not. Normally I use len(list) == 0 and I vaguely remembered reading a little while ago that the correct way to test if a list is empty was whether it was True or false.

So I tried list is False, and that returned False. Maybe I'm suppose to be using == ?
Nope, that also returned false. list is True, returned false as did list == True.

Now I'm confused so I do a quick google and end up at: [Best way to check if a list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/python-what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

The top answer is:

```
if not a:
    print "List is empty"
```

So I search around some more and end up in the python manual where 4.1 states:

Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:

any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].

Now I'm plain confused. If I test a list as if not list, it works fine. But if an empty list is false, then why can't I just do if list is False or if list == False?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An empty list is not False, but when you convert it to a boolean, it converts to False.  Likewise for dicts, tuples, strings, etc.:

```
>>> [] == False
False
>>> bool([]) == False
True
>>> {} == False
False
>>> bool({}) == False
True
```

When you put something in the condition of an `if` clause, it is its boolean value that is used for testing the `if`.  That's why `if someList` is the same as `if bool(someList)`.  Likewise, `not foo` does a boolean not, so `not []` equals True.

Comment: Specifically, the [__nonzero__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.%5F%5Fnonzero%5F%5F) method is called

Answer (score 2):

As other have said, in python `bool([]) == False`.  One thing that is frequently exploited by python programmers is that the operators `and` and `or` don't (necessarily) return True/False.  Consider the following:

```
3 and 4  #returns 4
0 and 8  #returns 0 -- This is short-circuit evaluation
0 or 8   #returns 8
True or 0 #returns True -- This is short-circuit evaluation

[] or False #returns False
False or [] #returns []
```

What happens in an `if` statement is that the condition gets evaluated as above and then python implicitly calls `bool` on the result -- So you can think of it as:

```
if condition:
```

is the same thing as:

```
if bool(condition):
```

as far as python is concerned.  Similarly for the `not` operator:

```
not condition
```

is the same thing as

```
not bool(condition)
```

Answer (score 1):

`mylist is False` means "is the object named `mylist` *exactly the same object* as `False`?"

`mylist == False` means "is the object named `mylist` *equal to* `False`?

`not mylist` means "does the object named `mylist` behave falsily?

---

None of these are equivalent: `1 is not 1.0` but `1 == 1.0` and `[] != False` but `not [] is True`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the list to `False`, and testing the list's truth or falsehood aren't quite the same thing. An empty list isn't equal to `False`, but behaves as `False` in a boolean context.

Here's another way to say it that might help this make sense:

```
print (bool([]) == False) # will print True
print ([] == False) # will print False
```