# Python if a var doesn't exist then

Tags: python, if-statement, imap, imaplib

I'm developing some IMAP checker. Now the inbox count is prints a message in the following layout: ['*number*'].

Now that that number is split to the *number* in var num. See the following code:

```
for num in data[0].split():
    print num
```

Now the thing is, if there ain't any new emails num doesn't exist so I want an if statement like this:

```
if <num doesn't exist>: print "No new emails found."
```

But what should that if statement look like?

Comment: Is data the name of your list containing numbers - [number]? And please post the real list what it looks like.

Comment: you need 4 space before the `print`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most pythonic way to achieve what you seem to want to, is:

```
nums = data[0].split()
for num in nums:
   print num
if not nums:
   print "No new emails found"
```

since the code reflects the intention precisely.

Comment: Even though the edit was approved, I still think that `if-else` was a more readable option. Purely matter of personal taste, though.

Answer (score 6):

Check [this site](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/59892-testing-if-a-variable-is-defined/), they have a useful snippet to check if the variable exists or if it is None:

```
# Ensure variable is defined
try:
   num
except NameError:
   num = None

# Test whether variable is defined to be None
if num is None:
    some_fallback_operation()
else:
    some_operation(num)
```

Comment: why not just - `if num: some_operation(num) else: some_fallback_operation()`?

Comment: I decided to add both in case he wants to make a difference between an undefined variable and a None variable. Your solution also works though.

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of the split data and use that as your condition:

```
for num in data[0].split():
    print num
if len(data[0].split()) == 0:
    print "No new emails found."
```

More elegant way:

```
for num in data[0].split():
    print num
if not data[0].split():
    print "No new emails found."
```

Comment: There are many more ways to do the check. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/python-what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty).

Comment: Top example fixed now (had misplaced parenthesis and missing colon), in case someone comes back to this. Bottom example worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
num = None
for num in data[0].split(): 
    print num
if num is None:
    print "No new emails found."
```

If `None` is a valid data portion, use

```
num = sentinel = object()
for num in data[0].split(): 
    print num
if num is sentinel:
    print "No new emails found."
```

instead.