# Check if list is empty without using the `not` command

Tags: python, list, is-empty

How can I find out if a list is empty without using the not command?
Here is what I tried:

```
if list3[0] == []:  
    print("No matches found")  
else:  
    print(list3)
```

I am very much a beginner so excuse me if I do dumb mistakes.

Comment: What's wrong with `not`?

Comment: Its for a school task, and I'm not supposed to know not right now. I only know about it because I searched for the answer before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to check if a list is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

Comment: Top tip: `not` is an operator, not a command

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In order of preference:

```
# Good
if not list3:

# Okay
if len(list3) == 0:

# Ugly
if list3 == []:

# Silly
try:
    next(iter(list3))
    # list has elements
except StopIteration:
    # list is empty
```

If you have both an if and an else you might also re-order the cases:

```
if list3:
    # list has elements
else:
    # list is empty
```

Comment: Indeed, empty lists are `False` in a boolean context. No need to explicitly test for `len()`.

Comment: It should be noted that under the hood, `1` and `2` are really doing the same thing most of the time.

Comment: @sr2222 Sorry. Deleted comment due to syntax error in Python 2.x. Could do `None if list3 else print("No matches found")` in Python 3.x, though.

Comment: @Aya You could also do `try: iter(l).next()` `except StopIteration: #do stuff`.  Of course, 'can' and 'should' are different things...  Edit: Doh, John beat me to it... though `try: l[0]` `except IndexError: #do stuff` is equally silly...

Comment: @sr2222 Indeed. Although it'd be interesting to see how many crazy ways people can come up with. `list3 or print("No matches found")` might also do the trick. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You find out if a list is empty by testing the 'truth' of it:

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([0])     
True
```

While in the second case `0` is False, but the list `[0]` is True because it contains something. (If you want to test a list for containing all falsey things, use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) or [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any): `any(e for e in li)` is True if any item in `li` is truthy.)

This results in this idiom:

```
if li:
    # li has something in it
else:
    # optional else -- li does not have something 

if not li:
    # react to li being empty
# optional else...
```

According to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), this is the proper way:

> • For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.
>
> ```
> Yes: if not seq:
>      if seq:
>
> No: if len(seq)
>     if not len(seq)
> ```

You test if a list has a specific index existing by using `try`:

```
>>> try:
...    li[3]=6
... except IndexError:
...    print 'no bueno'
... 
no bueno
```

So you may want to reverse the order of your code to this:

```
if list3:  
    print list3  
else:  
    print "No matches found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check its length.

```
l = []
print len(l) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you would do that

```
if len(list3) == 0:
    print("No matches found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python provides an inbuilt any() function to check whether an iterable is empty or not:

```
>>>list=[]

>>>any(list)

False
```

The function returns True if the iterable contains a 'True' value, and False otherwise.

However, note that the list [0] also returns False with any().