# evaluating values of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the values are a tuple

```
dict={'A':('1','2','3'),'B':('2','3','xxxx')....}
```

I need to find out if all values have a '' or None in their third element.
It just needs to be a boolean evaluation.
What is most concise way to make this happen?

This is what I did:

```
all(not v[2] for v in dict.values())
```

But  i guess there will be a better 'any' form to this?

Comment: Could an attempt on your part be shown?

Comment: What do you mean by "'any' form"? Are you asking if there is a way to write this is with `any()` instead? It'd be `any(v[2] is not None and v[2] != '' for v in dict.values())`. By the way, if you are checking for `''` or `None` you shouldn't rely on the truthiness of these two, since you could also mistakenly evaluate the truthiness of, say, an integer or list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use (Use itervalues() for Py2x)

```
all(elem[2] in ('', None) for elem in test.values())
```

See the demo -

```
>>> test = {'a': (1, 2, None), 'b':(2, 3, '')}
>>> all(elem[2] in ('', None) for elem in test.values())
True
>>> test['c'] = (1, 2, 3)
>>> all(elem[2] in ('', None) for elem in test.values())
False
```

Comment: Calling `values()` will create list of dictionary values, which could be large. `itervalues()` would be a better choice, like in @JAB's solution.

Comment: @nofinator : My apologies. I tested this code on Py3x and completely forgot about adding itervalues. Thanks for reminding me. :)

Answer (score 4):

Python 2:

```
boolean = all(value[2] in ('', None) for value in your_dict.itervalues())
```

Python 3:

```
boolean = all(value[2] in ('', None) for value in your_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
all(dict[k][2] is None or dict[k][2] == "" for k in dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x and y[2] not in ('', None), d.values(), True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple functional solution:

```
not filter( lambda l : not l, [ v[2] for v in d.values()] )
```

It will return `False` if `''` or `None` is not found in the third position, and `True` if one of those values is found. Partially adapted from [Best way to check if a list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty).