# What is the practical application of bool() in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean

When it is being used in everyday coding? I am learning Python using [this tutorial](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/). What am I referring to is described [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch04.html) (middle of the page), but I can't get it. I understand the principles of using True and False, but I don't get when (or do) we actually use the `bool()` function in practice while writing our code. It would help me if you give the everyday, practical example of `bool()` in code.

Comment: Check the docs. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool

Comment: It lets you convert any Python value to a boolean value. What part about this is unclear?

Comment: Thanks to `bool` you can do stuff like `if some_list:` instead of `if len(some_list) > 0:` or `if foo` instead of `if foo != None:` where it is used implicitly according to [there rules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth)

Comment: I have already, but I still don't get it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I know about that part (@tobias_k), but when we'll use this bool() in code? That thing you described doesn't request bool().

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić Personally, I can't remenber ever using it. It is more used internally, in conditions and such where a boolean is expected, calling an objects `__bool__` magic method.

Comment: @tobias_k: objects had a truth value in a boolean context *way* before Python grew a proper boolean type, so tests like `if some_list:` are in no way "thanks to `bool`"

Comment: I didn't know the real purpose of bool() (in the code). I got it thanks to @MartijnPieters. We can use bool() in the code if we want to assign boolean state (True or False) of some object depending on another one. Instead of writing the if statement (which is longer) we use bool(), as described in Martin's answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It lets you convert any Python value to a boolean value.

Sometimes you want to store either `True` or `False` depending on another Python object. Instead of:

```
if python_object:
    result = True
else:
    result = False
```

you simply do:

```
result = bool(python_object)
```

*How* Python objects are converted to a boolean value, all depends on their [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth). Generally speaking, `None`, numeric 0 and empty containers (empty list, dictionary, set, tuple, string, etc.) are all `False`, the rest is `True`.

You use it whenever you need an explicit boolean value. Say you are building an object tree, and you want to include a method that returns `True` if there are children in the tree:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = children

    def has_children(self):
        return bool(self.children)
```

Now `Tree().has_children()` will return `True` when `self.children` is not empty, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

To understand what `bool()` does we need to first understand the concept of a boolean.

A boolean variable is represented by either a 0 or 1 in binary in most programming languages. A 1 represents a "True" and a 0 represents a "False"

The number 1 is different from a boolean value of True in some respects. For example, take the following code:

```
>>> 1 is True
False
```

Notice that 1 is different than True according to Python. However:

```
>>> bool(1) is True
True
```

When we use the `bool()` function here, we convert 1 to a boolean. This conversion is called "casting". Casting 1 to boolean returns the value of "True".

Most objects can be cast to a boolean value. From my experience, you should expect every standard object to evaluate to True unless it is 0, None, False or an empty iterable (for example: "", [], or {}). So as an example:

```
>>> bool({})
False
>>> bool({"":False})
True
>>> bool(None)
False
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("hello")
True
>>> bool(500)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(False)
False
>>> bool(-1)
True
```

Lastly, a boolean prints as either "True" or "False"

```
>>> print bool(1)
True
```

Comment: Note that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so `True` and `False` can be used in arithmetic contexts.

Comment: Worth including that `bool(-1) is True`.

Comment: @psilocybin - thanks, edited to reflect that case as well

Answer (score 4):

`bool` exposes the fact that Python allows for boolean conversions to things that you wouldn't typically consider to be True or False.

An example of this is lists. If `len(my_list)` would be greater than 0, it also treats this as `True`. If it has no length -- if `len()` would return 0 -- it is `False`. This lets you write code like this:

```
def check_list_for_values(my_list, value):
    return [x for x in my_list if x == value]

your_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8]
if check_list_for_values(3, your_list):
    print "got a match"
```

If `check_list_for_values` returns a list that has length greater than 0, then it prints "got a match" because it evaluates to `True`. If there is no length to the list that would be returned...

```
your_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8]
if check_list_for_values('elephant', your_list):
    print "got a match"
```

Then there will be nothing printed, because it evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score -1):

Converts a value to a boolean.

Comment: you quote the doc, but you don't link it. moreover, you omit the part where the doc explains what `convert (...) to a boolean` means and is done. I don't understand the purpose of this answer.