# Python one-line sum implementation?

Tags: python, list, sum

First of all, I ask this question by pure curiosity to see some great one-liners skills. The `sum()` function remains the best function to sum objects in a list.

But as said, I ask by pure curiosity: Is there a way to sum objects from a `list` (obviously, without using `sum()`) in one line? Let's say the list would be `range(0, 100)`

I have absolutely no idea how this could be achieved, but as Python is really great and flexible, so I have no doubt it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, here's a solution that needs no no built-in functions at all. It's basically a reimplentation of `reduce`, using a bit of lambda magic.

```
>>>>(lambda f: lambda *args: f(f, *args))(lambda self, f, seq, d: d if not seq else f(seq[0], self(self, f, seq[1:], d)))(lambda a,b: a+b, range(100), 0)
4950
```

Comment: Wow, That was the kind of thing I was thinking. I'll need my time to understand that one!

Answer (score 5):

You can take a functional approach, using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and an addition function (e.g. a [`lamdba` expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) or [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add)):

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> reduce(add, range(0, 100))
4950
```

*(Note that in 3.x you need to `from functools import reduce` first.)*

Per the documentation, `reduce(function, iterable)` will

> Apply `function` of two arguments cumulatively to the items of `iterable`, from left to right, so as to reduce the `iterable` to a single value.

Comment: Well, I didn't expected something so short, I'll let the thread open for some times to see some other proposals, even if this one is really KISS

Comment: @CarlierRobin how long a *"one-line... implementation"* were you expecting?

Comment: You can also replace `add` with `lambda x, y: x + y`, so that this does not even need imports in Python 2.

Comment: @jonrsharpe To be honest I had in mind someone that one able to code big script in one instruction, just for fun. Obviously the script was enormous. So in my mind it was a long long thing. I didn't new there were a  builtin function that does that and was thinking on how do this sum without thing like that. Even if this sol is great!

Comment: @CarlierRobin maybe you should look at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com. You know, just for fun.

Comment: @kokiro It could indeed more be the place to aks this, you're right, I'll let this open and feel free to do a close vote on this one

Comment: It's not really code golf, as that aims to minimise length. I don't think SE has a site for needless complexity!

Comment: `reduce` is so good it's been removed from Python3. :-/ "batteries included except when we arbitrarily decide to remove useful batteries".

Comment: @EricDuminil just moved; as I say in the question you can still import it from within the standard library. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes, but it's still doesn't explain why it's been moved in the first place. There are many other, less useful functions that are directly available without `import`. Why not remove `map` for example? You can use a comprehension instead, which is more readable. There's no other readable, short alternative to `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't change my opinion one bit. Basically, `reduce` has been moved because it's possible to write unclear code with it. With this reasoning, you could remove every function and operator from standard Python.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm just trying to give you information, not attacking or defending the choice to move it; it's up to the BDFL. If you have a problem with it, I can only suggest you take it to the mailing list.

Comment: Sorry, that was nothing personal. I like your answer and upvoted it. When I don't agree with some Python designs (it doesn't happen too regularly), I look at JS code for 5 minutes and suddenly, Python looks much clearer and cleaner. My other whish for Python : a standard `flatten` function :)

Answer (score 1):

Python may not be the best language for recursive approaches because (1) it doesn't support tail-recursion (2) function calls are really expensive (3) the recursion limit prevents deep recursions and (4) slicing sequences scales with `O(n)` (where `n` is the number of elements in the slice).

However you can use them for one-liners!

One approach would be just to successivly pop and add the first element until the sequence is exhausted:

```
>>> sum_func = lambda x: x[0] + sum_func(x[1:]) if x else 0
>>> sum_func(range(100))
4950
```

The first part is triggered as long as `if x` ([that is to say `x` is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53513/5393381)). This approach shows all the shortcomings of using recusion in Python: It hits the recursion limit for sequences of length ~300, it scales with `O(n**2)` and it's really slow compared to the built-in `sum` and `reduce` approach.

One can mitigate one of the disadvantages by using a divide-and-conquer recursion approach:

```
>>> sum_func = lambda x: sum_func(x[:len(x)//2]) + sum_func(x[len(x)//2:]) if len(x) > 1 else x[0]
>>> sum_func(range(100))
4950
```

This time it recurses on both halfs of the list, thereby reducing the recusion depth from `n` to `log2(n)`, so it can handle even longer sequences. However it's not faster than the one above.

---

And of course there's always the cheat option:

```
>>> from numpy import sum
>>> sum(range(100))
4950
```

In case you really want it really fast :-)

Comment: @EricDuminil yes, because slicing is `O(n)`. But that's not going to matter much because before that's significant the function hits the recursion limit. And the constant factor (repeatedly calling the function) is huge.