# cost of len() and pep8 suggestion on sequence empty check

Tags: python, pep8

If the complexity of python `len()` is O(1), why does pep8 suggest to use 
`if seq:` instead of `if len(seq) == 0:`

> https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
>   https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Isn't `len(seq) == 0` more readable?

Comment: For me, something exist if it has content so 'if seq' is clear and simple for me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to check if a list is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

Answer (score 8):

The former can handle both empty string and `None`. For example consider these two variables.

```
>>> s1 = ''
>>> s2 = None
```

Using the first method

```
def test(s):
    if s:
        return True
    else:
        return False

>>> test(s1)
False
>>> test(s2)
False
```

Now using `len`

```
def test(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

>>> test(s1)
True
>>> test(s2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    test(s2)
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in test
    if len(s) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

So in terms of performance, both will be O(1), but the truthiness test (the first method) is more robust in that it handles `None` in addition to empty strings.

Comment: The explanation is very interesting. Isn't it a better practice to just check if it is not None before checking the `len()`? I don't like to use non-boolean values inside if/while clauses

Comment: @SomethingSomething Absolutely. In fact the observation in this answer is pretty useless. In real code when you check if a sequence is either empty or not empty is because you then want to perform some operation on it (e.g. indexing, appending, removing etc). Those don't work with `None` anyway rendering this observation useless in 99% of the cases. A remaining 0.99% would be clearer using `seq is/is not None`.

Comment: It depends a bit on your code, but the only reason to have separate checks is if you'll actually treat them separately. So if you do something different when you find None, then the separate test makes sense, but not if None and "" both lead to the same outcome.

Comment: @SomethingSomething but using non-boolean values in conditionals is idiomatic for python.

Comment: @Bakuriu That's not true, there's plenty of cases where you'll want to perform the same action whether you got None or an empty variable. In those cases having two if statements is redundant.

Comment: " I don't like to use non-boolean values inside if/while clauses" : Python objects DO have a boolean value, cf https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__ - so `if x:` is just the same as `if bool(x):` (which evals to either `True` or `False`).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan In my experience that's not the case. An empty collection is the perfect default value for "no values". Only in exceptional cases you want to distinguish between an empty collection and no collection at all and in those cases, since you need the distinction, you *have* to treat them differently (otherwise you could simply avoid using `None`). The point is: if you treat them in the same way you can just get rid of `None` and use `''` or `()` directly. If you treat them differently, then the correct check is doing `is None`. You need the intersection of cases to make this useful.

Comment: @Bakuriu I guess our cases just differ? I've often used it when a function can return an empty value like `[]` or `''` but if there's an issue like a try except block exiting early I end up with a None value instead. For the purposes of checking for a value it doesn't matter if I have empty or None, I don't have the value there. But I do want to preserve the difference so I can later note that the value is None and there was a problem with retrieving it.

Answer (score 5):

The fact the `len` is O(1) is only a convention. There may be sequences/collections where `len` is *not* O(1) at that point checking `len(x) == 0` *could* take asymptotically more time.

The fact is: the question "is the size of this collection equal to `k`?" and "is the collection empty?" are fundamentally different problems. The first is answered by `len(x) == k` and the latter by `bool(x)` [i.e. is `x` truthy]. Hence if you want to check if the collection is empty you just use `if collection`. They just happen to coincide if `k == 0`.

Generally you should use the most specific term to describe exactly what you are doing. Writing `len(x) == 0` may just be a typo for `len(x) == 10` with a missing `1` while getting `if x` wrong is harder.

Comment: How on earth is `if x` more *specific* than `if len(x) == 0`. The latter checks if `x` is an empty container. The former checks if `x` is 0, or an empty string, or an empty container, or None, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For `if len(seq) == 0`, you have to parse that

1. you are calling a function,
2. you are checking if its return value is equal to something, and
3. that "something" is 0.

For `if seq`, you only have to parse that `seq` is being evaluated in a Boolean context.

You might argue that you also have to know what  type `seq` has so you know what it means to evaluate it in a Boolean context, but then you also have to do know the type for `len(seq)` as well, so that you what it means to compute its length. (For example, for a dict `d`, `len(d)` says nothing about the values in the dictionary, only how many keys it has.)