# Check for empty list

Tags: python, list

I have the following output but I want to eliminate the empty lists.  How can I do this?  It seems that the single quote within the list make it seems like there is something in the list.

```
[{'Segment': {'Price': 305, 'Mw': 13, '@Number': '1'}}]
[{'Segment': {'Price': 258.43, 'Mw': 46.9, '@Number': '1'}}] 
['']
['']
['']
```

I tried using the code below but it did not work.

```
if not a:   
    print "List is empty"
```

Comment: What are the possible list contents?  Does each list only contain one item?  Are there any other "empty" values you want to eliminate, or just `['']`?

Comment: I just need to eliminate ['']  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is not empty, it has one  empty string on it. You can use `''.join` and check as answered:

```
if not ''.join(a):
   do your thing
```

I guess you can use `any` as well on this if your list is sure to have just empty strings.

```
if any(a):
    do your thing
```

Comment: I was thinking that, but `any()` also returns True on a truly empty list.

Comment: @gojomo Do you mean `any([])` will be True? I think `all([])` is True  and  not `any`.The problem I  see  with any is  if the list allows other values  as  [0] etc  where `any` is wrong.

Comment: Yep, never mind, I was still thinking in mode of question, trying to trigger on the 'empty-or-filled-with-empties' condition, and had just tested `all()`. Using `any()` to trigger positive action or `not any()` to trigger the nothing-there handling (like discarding the list) should work.

Answer (score 2):

What you had was a list with a single entry with empty string. It's not an empty list. [Best way to check if a list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty) is a correct way to check for empty list.

If you want to check for [''] just do

```
if a == ['']:
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
if ''.join(out[0]) != "":
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Python counts the empty string as a string. Use a regex if you need to, or merely:

```
if list[0] != '':
    print(list)
```

Plug that conditional into a For loop as necessary.

Comment: what about ls = ['', 1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
old_list=[[{'Segment': {'Price': 305, 'Mw': 13, '@Number': '1'}}], 
   [{'Segment': {'Price': 258.43, 'Mw': 46.9, '@Number': '1'}}], [''], ['']]

new_list = []

for i in old_list:
    if i != ['']:
        new_list.append(i)

print new_list
[[{'Segment': {'Price': 305, '@Number': '1', 'Mw': 13}}], [{'Segment': {'Price': 258.43, '@Number': '1', 'Mw': 46.9}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can i try this way:

```
>>> def is_empty(ls):
...     if all([not len(ls), not ls]):
...         print "List is empty"
...     else:
...         print "List is not empty"
...
>>> is_empty([])
List is empty
>>> is_empty([""])
List is not empty
>>> is_empty([{'Segment': {'Price': 305, 'Mw': 13, '@Number': '1'}}])
List is not empty
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not empty, it contains an empty string.

If you want to check that your list contains any items that are non-empty you can either use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
list = [ '' ]
if any(list):
    # List contains non-empty values
```

or you can [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) it before you use it to remove any empty strings:

```
list = [ '' ]
list = filter(None, list) # Remove empty values from list
if list:
    # List contains items
```