# How to skip empty lists when iterating over lists within a list?

Tags: python, list, iteration

Take the following code as an example:

```
a = [['James Dean'],['Marlon Brando'],[],[],['Frank Sinatra']]

n = 0

for i in a:
    print a[n][0]
    n = n + 1
```

I seem to be getting an error with the index value:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I skip over the empty lists within the list named `a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the list is empty or not, empty lists have `False` value in boolean context -

```
for i in a:
    if i:
        print a[n][0]
    n = n + 1
```

Also, instead of using `n` separately, you can use the `enumerate` function , which returns the current element as well as the index -

```
for n, i in enumerate(a):
    if i:
        print a[n][0] # though you could just do - print i[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple:

```
for i in a:
    if i:
        print i[0]
```

This answer works because when you convert a list (like `i`) to a boolean in an `if` statement like I've done here, it evaluates whether the list is *not* empty, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could either make a test, or catch the exception.

```
# Test
for i in a:
    if a[n]:
        print a[n][0]
    n = n + 1

# Exception
for i in a:
    try:
        print a[n][0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    finally:
        n = n + 1
```

You could even use the condensed `print "\n".join(e[0] for e in a if e)` but it's quite less readable.

Btw I'd suggest using using `for i, element in enumerate(a)` rather than incrementing manually `n`

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, I assume you try to get the first element of the inner list for every non empty entry in the list, and print that. I like this syntax:

```
a = [['James Dean'],['Marlon Brando'],[],[],['Frank Sinatra']]
# this filter is lazy, so even if your list is very big, it will only process it as needed (printed in this case)
non_empty_a = (x[0] for x in a if x)

for actor in non_empty_a : print (actor)
```

As mentioned by other answers, this works because an empty list is converted to False in an if-expression