# How to check if a nested list has a value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a **nested** list and I want to check if an item has a value or not.

Not really sure how to describe it, so basically, how do I get this to work?

```
list = [ [item1, a, b], [item2, a, b], [item3, a] ]

if list[2][2] #is empty (has no value):
    print("There is no value at list[2][2]!")
else:
    print("There is a value at list[2][2]")
```

Comment: A list is boolean False if it's empty. So you could do 'if list[2]' or check len(list[2]) to see how many entries it has. By the way 'list' is a reserved word, you should better use some other variable name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty

Comment: `if len(L) > 2 and len(L[2]) > 2:`.

Comment: See what error happens when you try to access list[2][2], then catch that error using Python's exception handling mechanism. Also, avoid using variable names that are in the Python built-ins, like 'list'.

Comment: "if list[2]" gives me an "IndexError: list index out of range" error. But the "len(list[2]" idea does work, Thanks!

Comment: In general it's better to create your lists to be homogeneous. That is, each item in the list behaves like the other items. It's not required, but to do otherwise makes for much more complicated programs.

Comment: what's wrong with the `IndexError`? can't you just `catch` it? (see @dallen's answer)

Comment: @ChadSimmons agreed. This looks like it should be a list of tuples to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using EAFP (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission). It is a very common coding pattern in python that assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false.

```
try:
    item = list[2][2]
except IndexError:
    print 'There is no value at list[2][2]'
else:
    print '{} is at list[2][2]'.format(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your list of sublist either using for-loop or while-loop, simultaneously check whether it has elements or not and print them. Hope this helps. Thanks

```
list = [[1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 7], ['', 'stack', 'overflow']]
i = 0
j = 0
while i<3:
    j = 0
    while j<3:
        print list[i][j]
        if list[i][j] == '':
            print "Has no element at", i, ",", j
            break
        else:
            print "has elements"
            j += 1
    i += 1

print "Successfully checked"
```