# if listA== [ ] more simplified version

Tags: python, list, pycharm

When I type in the following code, PyCharm says "Expression can be further simplified". What is the more simplified version to this statement?

```html
if listA == []:
  return "yes!"
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty

Comment: If anyone finds it useful, I created a youtube tutorial comparing the different ways to check if list is empty https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8V88bl3tuBQ. This is discussed in the PEP as well https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Empty lists evaluate as falsy, so you can also do this, which is what PyCharm may be talking about:

```
if not listA:
    return "yes!"
```

There are some side effects since the above code will return "yes!" whenever list is `False`, an empty string (`""`), `None`, an empty dict (`{}`), an empty set (`set()`) and basically anything else that python treats as falsy