# Flaw in hangman program

Tags: python

I need to write a simple hangman function that takes in one string (the word that's being guessed) and a list of letters (the letters that are guessed).
This is the code I'm using:

```
def WordGuessed(Word, letters):
    if letters == []:
        return False
    else:
        for i in letters:
            if i not in Word:
                return False
        else:
            if i == letters[-1]:
                return True
```

The code usually works, but I am finding that occasionally prints the wrong answer. For example, if

```
WordGuessed('durian', ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't', 'u'])
```

It prints False when it should be printing True. Can anyone see where my code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jonhopkins said it right: instead of checking that word contains all guessed letters we should check if all word's letters were guessed.

But your code can be much cleaner:

- if you need to check if `list` instance is empty just [use negation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522/5997596),
- if we've reached `else` block of `for`-`else` that means that we've reached the end of iterable without `return`ing or `break`ing, no need to additionally check that.

So solution can be written as

```
def WordGuessed(Word, letters):
    if not letters:
        return False
    else:
        for i in Word:
            if i not in letters:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

Finally, since we only need to check letters appearance once, we can work with unique collections of letters like [`set`s](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
def WordGuessed2(Word, letters):
    return set(Word).issubset(set(letters))
```

## Test

```
>>> word = 'durian'
>>> guessed_letters = ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't']
>>> WordGuessed(word, guessed_letters)
False
>>> WordGuessed2(word, guessed_letters)
False
>>> guessed_letters.append('u')
>>> WordGuessed(word, guessed_letters)
True
>>> WordGuessed2(word, guessed_letters)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning False as soon as you find a guessed letter that is not in the word. In your example, the very first letter is not in the word.

It would work if instead you loop through `Word` and check each letter if it is in the array `letters`:

```
def WordGuessed(Word, letters):
    if letters == []:
        return False
    else:
        for i in Word:
            if i not in letters:
                return False
        else:
            if i == Word[-1]:
                return True

# prints True
print(WordGuessed('durian', ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't', 'u']))

# prints False, missing 'u'
print(WordGuessed('durian', ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't']))
```